# Exif manipulation library for python

Tags: python, exif

I'm looking for good exif (Exchangeable image file format) manipulation library for python. I prefer flexibility (e.g., ability to retrieve providers' proprietary tags) than processing speed. What would you suggest?

Comment: Perhaps the question should read: "What options are available to edit Exif (Exchangeable image file format) using python that emphasize feature set (e.g. ability to retrieve providers' proprietary tags and compatiblity with a wide variety of image formats) over speed?"

Comment: @Wooble et al: "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment." I did the latter, but the Q closed without further comment. What gives? (Just trying to understand, and don't want to waste time commenting/editing questions if its a foregone conclusion)

Comment: I wanted other developers opinions when asking this question! PackageOpinionOverflow?

Comment: Keep in mind that pretty much all non-exiv2 solutions here will not be able to access `MakerNote`. In this EXIF tag, camera manufacturers add their own tags that hold valuable information. So you would only get the basic tags with most libraries from the below answers.

Answer (score 65):

You might want to check out [exif-py](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py):

> Python library to extract EXIF data from tiff and jpeg files. Very easy to use - $ ./EXIF.py image.jpg

or the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/):

> The Python Imaging Library (PIL) adds image processing capabilities to your Python interpreter. This library supports many file formats, and provides powerful image processing and graphics capabilities.

There's also the aptly named pyexif: http://pyexif.sourceforge.net/

> The pyexif python library and tools aims at extracting EXIF information from Jpeg and Tiff files which include it. This information is typically included in images created using digital imaging devices such as digital cameras, digital film scanners, etc.

However, it looks like pyexif hasn't been updated in quite while. They recommend if theirs isn't doing the trick to check out EXIF-py, so you should probably try that one first, as their sourceforge page seems to have *some* activity there lately, though not much. Finally,  using PIL you could do this:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    info = i._getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret
```

**Disclaimer**:
I actually have no idea which is best, this is just what I was able to piece together with Google. :)

Comment: None of these "solutions" can write EXIF tags back, so they are not a solution to the question.

Comment: Nice overview. Just a note: exif-py is currently not compatible with Python 3.x it seems (tested with Python 3.3.3, see also https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/issues/12).

Answer (score 59):

I've been using [pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/) myself recently, and it seems to fit my needs quite nicely. Perhaps it might suit yours as well.

Note: pyexiv2 is only for python2, for python3 use [py3exiv2](https://python3-exiv2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: For the record: pyexiv2 seems to be the best-maintained of them all, and the most complete (including writing EXIF tags back to the file).

Comment: Can pyexiv2 easily be installed inside a virtualenv?

Comment: Maintenance seems to be slowed down, and installation on Mac is a hell. :/

Comment: For those who care: Unfortunately, pyexiv2 is only available for Python 2.

Comment: <QUOTE src="http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/gexiv2/wiki">
This will work equally well with either Python 2 or 3, which makes GExiv2 an excellent replacement for pyexiv2, which only supports Python 2.
</QUOTE>

Comment: Can you test this on this Question, download the images, and try to get the ImageDescription. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173902/how-to-get-image-title-in-python-django

Comment: Can I access time stamps of my image using pyexiv?

Answer (score 31):

### Exiv2 Based solutions

Exiv2 (exiv2: http://exiv2.org/) is a mature, open-source C++ library that supports reading and writing metadata to many image types (JPEG, PNG, TIFF and many raw formats), understands standard (Xmp, IPTC and Exif) and non-standard metadata ("Makernotes"), and runs on multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, and, with some work, Mac).

Python bindings to exiv2 are:

- gexiv2 (a multi-language binding, but works with python 2.6/2.7/3.X): https://wiki.gnome.org/gexiv2
- pyexiv2 (no longer supported, but works with python 2.6/2.7): http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/

One advantage of pyexiv2 is that there is a windows build available for python 2.7. A windows build request for gexiv2 is here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712441

exiv2 and the bindings are all open source (GPL).

Comment: updated this based on latest info about bindings to exiv2

Comment: `pyexiv2` has been forked: http://www.py3exiv2.tuxfamily.org/.

Comment: tilloy.net link dead

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://www.fetidcascade.com/pyexif.html) describes a Python module for writing EXIF metadata (and not just reading them) using pure Python. Apparently, none of PIL, pyexif, nor EXIF-py support writing EXIF. pyexiv2 appears to be bleeding-edge and platform-specific.

Comment: Not sure if this can be considered any less bleeding edge.

Answer (score 4):

Use PIL :)

```
import os,sys
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for (k,v) in Image.open(sys.argv[1])._getexif().iteritems():
        print '%s = %s' % (TAGS.get(k), v)
    os.system('pause')
```

Comment: Pure PIL / Pillow does not allow modifying EXIF tags. But there a small library helping with that: https://github.com/hMatoba/Pyxif

Answer (score 4):

The page at http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/gexiv2/wiki (became https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2) reads **now**:

> This will work equally well with either Python 2 or 3, which makes
>   GExiv2 an excellent replacement for pyexiv2, which only supports
>   Python 2.

So, both Python2 and Python3 are now supported by GExiv2.

Good news.

Comment: the link does not work. this works https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2

Comment: good update! 3 years have passed since 2013...

Answer (score 3):

You might also look at Gheorghe Milas' jpeg.py library at http://www.emilas.com/jpeg/, which is "A python library to parse, read and write JPEG EXIF, IPTC and COM metadata."

A drawback is that he appears to be hosting his domain on a dynamic IP via DynDNS, so it's not always available.

Comment: Does not exist any longer.

Answer (score 3):

I started to write my own small library which is based on the code in PIL.
[check it here](https://github.com/albertz/helpers/blob/master/exif.py).

Comment: Hey that looks good. Any sharp edges with it?

Comment: @Rich: I don't remember anymore. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

somehow i get an attributeError for _getexif with Paolo's code above.. I am using Python 2.6.6 and PIL 1.1.7.  Is _getexif obsolete now??

Here's a small modification that worked for me.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
#    info = i._getexif()
    info = i.tag.tags
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been using my own wrappers around http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
-- the reason is that it is very complete, the dev is very active. And not being able to support almost all image formats is a absolute showstopper for the project it is needed for

The drawback of course is that it isn't python, so you would need to use subprocess calls, as I do.

Comment: There's a python wrapper for exiftool https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool. One vote for exiftool for the fact that it is very complete.

Comment: He's asking for a Python lib.

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples of PIL and EXIF.py usage on [ASPN](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/tags/EXIF/)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.6 the place of module is different. Use this:

```
import Image    
from ExifTags import TAGS
```