# Python PIL has no attribute 'Image'

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library

I'm using python2.6 and got a problem this morning. It said 'module' has no attribute 'Image'. Here is my input. Why the first time I can not use PIL.Image?

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Image'
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image
<module 'PIL.Image' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc'>
>>> PIL.Image
<module 'PIL.Image' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

PIL's `__init__.py` is just an empty stub as is common. It won't magically import anything by itself.

When you do `from PIL import Image` it looks in the PIL package and finds the file Image.py and imports that. When you do `PIL.Image` you are actually doing an attribute lookup on the PIL module (which is just an empty stub unless you explicitly import stuff).

In fact, importing a module usually **doesn't** import submodules. `os.path` is a famous exception, since the os module is magic.

More info:
[The Image Module](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)

Answer (score 50):

If you, like me, found the accepted answer a bit befuddling because you could *swear* you've been able to use

```py
import PIL
PIL.Image
```

sometimes before, a potential reason for this is if **any** other code in your Python session has run `from PIL import Image` or `import PIL.Image`, even if it's in a completely different scope, *you will be able to access `PIL.Image`*.

In particular, `matplotlib` does so when it's imported. So if you run

```
import matplotlib
import PIL
PIL.Image
```

*it works*. Thanks, Python.

Don't trust anyone. Don't trust Python. Use `import PIL.Image`.

Comment: this answer is eye-opening and should be a part of the main answer

Comment: This behavior is a core feature of the Python import system (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache ) which ensure that different parts of the process have the same view of what an imported module is.  Without this it would be impossible to use module-level sentinels or to safely pass objects wrapping c-extensions between different parts of your program.

Answer (score 9):

You can do:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
```

it's better to use pillow instead PIL.

Answer (score 1):

***The solution is***

instead of using this form

```
import PIL
PIL.Image
```

use this form

```
from PIL import Image
Image
```

***in the Linux system both forms work fine***

[image]

***but in windows, there is a problem***

[image]