# Pillow installed, but attributes not present

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I have installed pillow using the installer "Pillow-3.3.0.win32-py2.7.exe", but for some reason after I import it none of it's attributes are available. If I run the following code

```
import PIL
print(dir(PIL))
```

it will return

```
['PILLOW_VERSION', 'VERSION', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_plugins']
```

as you can see, all of pillow's attributes are missing. if I try to access an attribute by doing something like

```
PIL.Image.open(someImage)
```

it will return

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Image'
```

I had the same problem installing PIL. I've searched around the web, can't seem to find anything on why this is.
how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillow doesn't support `import PIL`. Use `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: Ok, now I have a new problem: when I do "from PIL import Image" I get "RuntimeWarning: The _image extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL" what does this mean?

Comment: Nevermind, re-installed python and Pillow and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911480/python-pil-has-no-attribute-image),

> PIL's **init**.py is just an empty stub as is common. It won't
>   magically import anything by itself.
>
> When you do from PIL import Image it looks in the PIL package and
>   finds the file Image.py and imports that. When you do PIL.Image you
>   are actually doing an attribute lookup on the PIL module (which is
>   just an empty stub unless you explicitly import stuff).