# Removing weights from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have written a python program which gives me the following output:

```
{'D': {('B', 2.0), ('E', 1.0), ('C', 2.0)}, 'E': {('D', 1.0), ('B', 4.0), ('C', 3.0)}, 

'A': {('B', 1.0), ('C', 5.0)}, 'B': {('A', 1.0), ('D', 2.0), ('E', 4.0)}, 'C': {('E', 3.0), 
('A', 5.0), ('D', 2.0)}`}`
```

These are nodes of a graph and their corresponding weights. I am trying to remove weights from the above output. Can anyone help me with this.? My output should look something like this :

```
{ "a" : ["b","c"],"b" : ["a", "e","d"],"c" : ["a", "d", "e"],
          "d" : ["b","c","e"],"e" : ["b", "c","d"] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{k:[x for x,_ in v] for k,v in d.items()} # use iteritems() in python 2
Out[32]: 
{'A': ['C', 'B'],
 'B': ['D', 'A', 'E'],
 'C': ['D', 'A', 'E'],
 'D': ['E', 'C', 'B'],
 'E': ['C', 'B', 'D']}
```

Comment: :Is it possible to write without using d.items..?

Comment: yes, in that case you will iterate over keys only, then use `d[k]` to use value at key

Comment: @Rachel perhaps you should explain the reason for that constraint..?  `items` is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: @roippi in Python-2. do dict compression has to be `dict()`  constructor, you just mentioned `iteritems()`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan no, dict comprehensions are in 2.7.

Comment: @roippi : Unfortunately, we cannot use in-built functions, we are required to understand the working of in-built functions.So cannot use .items

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan where should i use d[k] in the code??

Comment: @Rachel `{k: [x for x,_ in d[k]] for k in d}`

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {'D': {('B', 2.0), ('E', 1.0), ('C', 2.0)}, 
       'E': {('D', 1.0), ('B', 4.0), ('C', 3.0)}, 
       'A': {('B', 1.0), ('C', 5.0)}, 
       'B': {('A', 1.0), ('D', 2.0), ('E', 4.0)}, 
       'C': {('E', 3.0), ('A', 5.0), ('D', 2.0)}}

dic_node = {}
for node in dic:
    dic_node.update({node : [nnode for nnode, weigth in dic[node]]})

dic_node_one = {node : [nnode for nnode, weigth in dic[node]] for node in dic}
```

Out

```
>>> dic_node_one
{'A': ['C', 'B'],
 'B': ['A', 'E', 'D'],
 'C': ['A', 'D', 'E'],
 'D': ['B', 'E', 'C'],
 'E': ['B', 'C', 'D']}
>>> dic_node
{'A': ['C', 'B'],
 'B': ['A', 'E', 'D'],
 'C': ['A', 'D', 'E'],
 'D': ['B', 'E', 'C'],
 'E': ['B', 'C', 'D']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary comprehension, see [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
from operator import itemgetter

dic = {'D': {('B', 2.0), ('E', 1.0), ('C', 2.0)}, 
       'E': {('D', 1.0), ('B', 4.0), ('C', 3.0)}, 
       'A': {('B', 1.0), ('C', 5.0)}, 
       'B': {('A', 1.0), ('D', 2.0), ('E', 4.0)}, 
       'C': {('E', 3.0), ('A', 5.0), ('D', 2.0)}}

# Simply extracting only the 1st element of the tuple from the key.
print {k:[alpha for alpha, num in v] for k,v in dic.items()}
print
# Extracting only the 1st element and sorting the tuples by its 2nd element, ascending.
print {k:[alpha for alpha, num in sorted(v, key=itemgetter(1))] for k,v in dic.items()}
print
# Extracting only the 1st element and sorting the tuples by its 2nd element, descending.
print {k:[alpha for alpha, num in sorted(v, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)] for k,v in dic.items()}
print
# Extracting only the 1st element and sorting by alphabetical order.
print {k:[alpha for alpha, num in sorted(v)] for k,v in dic.items()}
print
# Extracting only the 1st element and sorting by alphabetical order, lower()
print {k.lower():[alpha.lower() for alpha, num in sorted(v)] for k,v in dic.items()}
```

[out]:

```
{'A': ['C', 'B'], 'C': ['A', 'D', 'E'], 'B': ['A', 'E', 'D'], 'E': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'D': ['B', 'E', 'C']}

{'A': ['B', 'C'], 'C': ['D', 'E', 'A'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'E'], 'E': ['D', 'C', 'B'], 'D': ['E', 'B', 'C']}

{'A': ['C', 'B'], 'C': ['A', 'E', 'D'], 'B': ['E', 'D', 'A'], 'E': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'D': ['B', 'C', 'E']}

{'A': ['B', 'C'], 'C': ['A', 'D', 'E'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'E'], 'E': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'D': ['B', 'C', 'E']}

{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'd', 'e'], 'b': ['a', 'd', 'e'], 'e': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'd': ['b', 'c', 'e']}
```