# How to form a dictionary with different parameters?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, set

I have a `class Test` with class parameter

`parameters = {'first': [1,2,3,4], 'second': [5,6,7]}`. I want to convert it into a dictionary so that it will be `"{'Test': 'first':1 'second':5}"`

what I tried is:

`di = {}
di = dict(itertools.izip(name, vals))`

where I'm getting Test i.e classnane in variable name i.e `name = Test` and

`vals = {'first': [1,2,3,4], 'second': [5,6,7]}`
Though I want it as `"{'Test': 'first':1 'second':5}"`, shouldn't this print `"{'Test': 'first':[1,2,3,4] 'second':[5,6,7]}"`?? Instead what I'm getting when I'm printing `di` is `{'Test': 'first'}`. I'm not getting where my logic is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
subjects = ['Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Maths']
{subject: {} for subject in subjects}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Python 2, you can use [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor:

```
subjects =  ['Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Maths']
dict(((subject, {}) for subject  in subjects))
```

If you are using Python 3, you can use [dictionary comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html#dictionary-comprehensions):

```
subjects =  ['Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Maths']
{subject: {} for subject in subjects}
```

Comment: This one gives TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: 2.7.7. I tried it with {subject: {} for subject in subjects} even with dict(((subject, {}) for subject  in subjects)) still same error.

Comment: It should work.  I think the error is referring to something else.  Maybe you have nested lists in your subjects list?

Comment: Nope, it's not nested list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using dict comprehension:

Input:

```
{x: {} for x in ['Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Maths']}
```

Output:

```
{'Maths': {}, 'Chemistry': {}, 'Physics': {}}
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants the items to be empty dicts -- If OP really wants an empty string, then `dict.fromkeys` is a great option.  c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14507591/748858

Comment: right, i realized that fact. dict comprehension is the solution to the question @mgilson

Answer (score 0):

That is a basic for loop. Itertools is way to complex for this kind of stuff.

```
>>> l = ['Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Maths']
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in l:
    d[i] ={}


>>> d
{'Chemistry': {}, 'Physics': {}, 'Maths': {}}
```

Comment: Hey I tried it and got working but I have one question why it's in different order? Instead of 
{'Physics': {}, 'Chemistry': {}, 'Maths': {}}
why we have - 
{'Chemistry': {}, 'Physics': {}, 'Maths': {}} ??
What I need to do to get it in right order?

Comment: In python a dict is not sorted. If you really need to go through the dict sorted, just use `for key in sorted(d):`. P.S. this is just a simple for loop, the other answers are more efficient, faster and generally better.