# weird python dict augement assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

I came across this weird issue this morning:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> dict = dict.fromkeys(l, [])
>>>　dict['a'] += [1]
>>> dict
{'a': [1], 'c': [1], 'b': [1]}
```

I can not explain why this happens?

Comment: I don't think you're posting the code you're actually using.

Comment: sorry, i used the dict.fromkeys function, I think i am closing the reason

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- Can't duplicate?  I can ... python2.7 and python3.2 on OS-X.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: duplicated on 3.4 on OSX

Comment: @mgilson: The OP edited the question, but it was in the 5-minute grace period so it doesn't show up as an edit.

Answer (score 4):

`dict.fromkeys` creates a whole bunch of references to *the same list*.  In other words, `d['a']` *is* `d['b']` etc.  When you do `+=` you extend the list *in place*, so modifications are seen in all the lists -- after all, they're the same list.

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(l, [])
>>> d
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}
>>> print [id(v) for v in d.values()]  # Note, they all have the same ID -- They're the same.
[4385936016, 4385936016, 4385936016]
>>> d['a'] += [1]
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'c': [1], 'b': [1]}
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, I didn't actually tell you how to get around this problem.  If you want to initialize a dictionary with keys that are instances of mutable values, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {key: [] for key in l}
```

Or, if you're stuck with an old version of python (before python2.7), you pass an iterable that yields 2-tuples to the dict constructor:

```
d = dict((key, []) for key in l)
```

Note that there are other variants as well that are useful to know about (`colections.defaultdict`, a regular dict subclass with overridden `__missing__`).  Each of these has slightly different behaviors that I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507623/748858).  However, this should be good enough to get you going for the time being...

Comment: A correct notation for what the poster was trying to do is `dict = {key: [] for key in l}`, giving each key its own unique list, i don't want to post a new answer when you've already got it nailed.

Comment: @user2085282 -- good point.  I suppose I should offer an alternative . . .

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a collections.defaultdict:

```
In [66]: d = collections.defaultdict(list)

In [67]: d['a'] += [1]

In [68]: d
Out[68]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1]})

In [69]: dict(d)
Out[69]: {'a': [1]}

In [70]: d['b']
Out[70]: []

In [71]: dict(d)
Out[71]: {'b': [], 'a': [1]}

In [72]: d['c']
Out[72]: []

In [73]: dict(d)
Out[73]: {'b': [], 'c': [], 'a': [1]}
```