# how to convert an array to a dict in python

Tags: python

Now, I wanna convert an array to a dict like this:

```
dict = {'item0': arr[0], 'item1': arr[1], 'item2': arr[2]...}
```

How to solve this problem elegantly in python?

Comment: It's a little weird to me that you would _want_ to do this.  Why change a nicely structured list/array into a dictionary?  You haven't added any information -- If anything, you've made it more difficult to recover the original order. . .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> arr = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
>>> {'item{}'.format(i): x for i,x in enumerate(arr)}
{'item2': 'cc', 'item0': 'aa', 'item1': 'bb'}
```

Comment: why I got invalid syntax Error when I tested your code? There is an arrow pointing to 'for'. I did not change anything.

Comment: @city -- What version of python are you using?  If you're on python2.6, then dict-comprehensions haven't been created yet.  You'd need to fall back on the old dict constructor:  `dict(('item{0}'.format(i), x) for i, x in enumerate(arr))`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a list of `int`s:

We can use a dict comprehension

```
>>> l = [3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 0, 9]
>>> d = {"item" + str(k): l[k] for k in range(len(l))}
>>> d
{'item5': 9, 'item4': 7, 'item7': 9, 'item6': 0, 'item1': 2, 'item0': 3, 'item3': 5, 'item2': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
simpleArray = [ 2, 54, 32 ]
simpleDict = dict()
for index,item in enumerate(simpleArray):
    simpleDict["item{0}".format(index)] = item

print(simpleDict)
```

Ok, first line Is the input, second line is an empty dictionary. We will fill it on the fly.

Now we need to iterate, but normal iteration as in C is considered non Pythonic. Enumerate will give the index and the item we need from the array. See this: [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops).

So in each iteration we will be getting an item from array and inserting in the dictionary with a key from the string in brackets. I'm using format since use of % is discouraged. See here: [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format).

At last we will print. Used print as function for more compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a dictionary comprehension
eg.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> {'item'+str(i):v for i, v in enumerate(x)}
>>> {'item2': 3, 'item0': 1, 'item1': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary comprehension: [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

So it'll look something like:

```
d = {"item%s" % index: value for (index, value) in enumerate(arr)}
```

Note the use of [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to give the index of each value in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `dict()` to construct your dictionary.

```
d = dict(('item{}'.format(i), arr[i]) for i in xrange(len(arr)))
```

Comment: Why down vote here? If you down vote an answer please mention the reason so that it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`, this could be solved as:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
d = list(map(lambda x: {f"item{x[0]}":x[1]}, enumerate(a)))
```

The result is:

```
[{'item0': 1}, {'item1': 2}, {'item2': 3}]
```