# What is this python expression containing curly braces and a for in loop?

Tags: python

I just came across this line of python:

```
order.messages = {c.Code:[] for c in child_orders}
```

I have no idea what it is doing, other than it is looping over the list `child_orders` and placing the result in `order.messages`.

What does it do and what is it called?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's a *dict comprehension*.

It is just like a *list comprehension*

```
 [3*x for x in range(5)]
 --> [0,3,6,9,12]
```

except:

```
{x:(3*x) for x in range(5)}
---> { 0:0, 1:3, 2:6, 3:9, 4:12 }
```

- produces a Python `dictionary`, not a `list`
- uses curly braces `{}` not square braces `[]`
- defines *key:value* pairs based on the iteration through a list

In your case the keys are coming from the `Code` property of each element and the value is always set to empty array `[]`

The code you posted:

```
order.messages = {c.Code:[] for c in child_orders}
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
order.messages = {}
for c in child_orders:
    order.messages[c.Code] = []
```

See also:

- [PEP0274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)
- [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Answer (score 12):

It's dictionary comprehension!

It's iterating through `child_orders` and creating a dictionary where the key is `c.Code` and the value is `[]`.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension).

Answer (score 2):

Just like list comprehension in Python, it's called dictionary comprehension.

```
sample_list = [2,4,6,8,9,10]
dict = {val: val**2 for val in sample_list if val**2 % 2 == 0}
print(dict)
//Output: {8: 64, 2: 4, 4: 16, 10: 100, 6: 36}
```

The code snippet above maps the numbers to their squares that are even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition, and since the question's title is very general: some people ending here might also be looking for the *set comprehension* as it also contains curly braces and a for loop. So a *set* comprehension would look like

```
order.messages = {c.Code for c in child_orders}
```

and it will return a Python set. In contrast to the former *dictionary* comprehension which will return a dictionary:

```
order.messages = {c.Code:[] for c in child_orders}
```