# Single line for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Can someone help me rewrite this single line loop to a multiple lines for loop in python?
I am trying to understand how it is formatted.

```
y = {element: r for element in variables(e)}
```

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Create an empty dictionary and add one item in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions **are not single line for-loops**. Do not think of them as such.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If the Python designers didn't want people to think of them like that, they shouldn't have used such similar syntax. :)

Comment: The title of the linked duplicate mentions list comprehensions, but the accepted answer includes dictionary comprehensions, and they are the same fundamental thing

Comment: @Barmar perhaps, but the language maintainers are big on re-using keywords whenever possible.

Comment: [Python List Comprehensions: Explained Visually](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

Comment: A better target: [What is this python expression containing curly braces and a for in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31846592/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary comprehension is equivalent to this loop:

```
y = {}
for element in variables(e):
    y[element] = r
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) in python.

This syntax builds a dictionary by taking each element in the list `variables(e)` and associating it with the value `r`.