# how does "x:set() for x in y" work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was looking at a python code which implemented topological sort and found the following code

```
data.update({item:set() for item in extra_items_in_deps})
```

I know what `data.update` does but am not sure how this:

```
item:set() for item in extra_items_in_deps
```

works.

Comment: It's a dictionary comprehension. Basically it creates a key/value pair according to the list it is iterating over. The value in this case is a new `set()` instance.

Comment: [Dict comp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: what do you not actually understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dictionary comprehension. It has the following syntax:

```
{ k: v for item in sequence }
```

This will create a dictionary entry for every `item` in `sequence` with the key `k` and the value `v`.

For example, the following will create a dictionary with the keys from the sequence `(1, 2, 3)`, and the squared number as the value:

```
>>> { x: x**2 for x in (1, 2, 3) }
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9}
```

In your case, you have the following dictionary comprehension:

```
{ item: set() for item in extra_items_in_deps }
```

This will create a dictionary with the keys from `extra_items_in_deps` and create a new *set* for each key. So assuming `extra_items_in_deps = [1, 2, 3]`, it’s equivalent to this dictionary:

```
{ 1: set(), 2: set(), 3: set() }
```

This dictionary is then passed to `data.update()` which updates the dictionary `data` with the key-value pairs from the passed dictionary.