# Get first element of sublist as dictionary key in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sublist

I looked but i didn't found the answer (and I'm pretty new to python).

The question is pretty simple. I have a list made of sublists:

```
ll
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a dictionary that has as key the first element of each sublist and as values the values of the coorresponding sublists, like:

```
d = {1:[2,3], 4:[5,6], 7:[8,9]}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) :

```
{words[0]:words[1:] for words in lst}
```

**output:**

```
{1: [2, 3], 4: [5, 6], 7: [8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using dictionary comprehension (For Python 2.7 +) and slicing -

```
d = {e[0] : e[1:] for e in ll}
```

Demo -

```
>>> ll = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> d = {e[0] : e[1:] for e in ll}
>>> d
{1: [2, 3], 4: [5, 6], 7: [8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do it this way:

```
ll = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
dct = dict( (item[0], item[1:]) for item in ll)
# or even:   dct = { item[0]: item[1:] for item in ll }
print(dct)
# {1: [2, 3], 4: [5, 6], 7: [8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation on the theme:

```
d = {e.pop(0): e for e in ll}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another:

```
d = {k: v for k, *v in ll}
```