# Convert every dictionary value to utf-8 (dictionary comprehension?)

Tags: python, utf-8, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary and I want to convert every value to utf-8.  This works, but is there a "more pythonic" way?

```
            for key in row.keys():
                row[key] = unicode(row[key]).encode("utf-8")
```

For a list I could do

```
[unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row]
```

but I'm not sure how to do the equivalent thing for dictionaries.

This is different from [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) because I'm not trying to create a dictionary from scratch, but from an existing dictionary.  The solutions to the linked question do not show me how to loop through the key/value pairs in the existing dictionary in order to modify them into new k/v pairs for the new dictionary.  The answer (already accepted) below shows how to do that and  is much clearer to read/understand for someone who has a task similar to mine than the answers to the linked related question, which is more complex.

Comment: I'm impressed you managed to come up with the right phrase (dictionary comprehension) but not to search for "python dictionary comprehension"!

Comment: why are you converting your keys to utf-8? this sounds like XY problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Dictionary Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: Danger Will Robinson! `unicode(row[key])` will use the system charset to decode `row[key]`. This implies that `row[key]` is already encoded to a specific character set. Further, you shouldn't encode until you need to output it somewhere, in which case, allow print to convert or write using a an encoding text wrapper, like `io.open()`

Comment: @DSM I found list comprehension, and extrapolated to dictionary comprehension, but didn't find a good example when I googled for it.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I am converting not my keys but my values to utf-8 because when I try to write them out with a CSV DictWriter it breaks on unicode strings that are outside of the ascii range.  Using Python 2.7

Comment: @PurpleVermont I would recommend using https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv instead of trying to write your own encoder/decoder

Comment: @JoranBeasley why is that better?  Having to install extra packages makes it a hassle for sharing the code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). It looks like you're starting with a dictionary so:

```
 mydict = {k: unicode(v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in mydict.iteritems()}
```

The example for dictionary comprehensions is near the end of the block in the link.

Answer (score 8):

Python 3 version building on that one answer by That1Guy.

```
{k: str(v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in mydict.items()}
```

Comment: You can simplify this further by calling `str(v, 'utf-8')`

Answer (score 5):

As I had this problem as well, I built a very simple function that allows any dict to be decoded in utf-8 (The problem with the current answer is that it applies only for simple dict).

If it can help anyone, it is great, here is the function :

```
def utfy_dict(dic):
    if isinstance(dic,unicode):
        return(dic.encode("utf-8"))
    elif isinstance(dic,dict):
        for key in dic:
            dic[key] = utfy_dict(dic[key])
        return(dic)
    elif isinstance(dic,list):
        new_l = []
        for e in dic:
            new_l.append(utfy_dict(e))
        return(new_l)
    else:
        return(dic)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends why you're implicitly encoding to UTF-8. If it's because you're writing to a file, the pythonic way is to leave your strings as Unicode and encode on output:

```
with io.open("myfile.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as my_file:
    for (key, values) in row.items():
        my_string = u"{key}: {value}".format(key=key, value=value)
        my_file.write(my_string)
```

Comment: I am, but I'm writing it with a csv DictWriter, and I'm not sure how to do the encoding on output in that case.

Comment: Python 2.x's CSV module is broken with Unicode, so the other contributor's answers are the easiest approach. If you want to do it properly, like Python3 does it, use a fixed CSV module: https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Comment: I can't use Python 3 for other reasons, but thanks for showing the "right way" to do it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the keys if you wanted to:

```
{x:unicode(a[x]).encode("utf-8") for x in a.keys()}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best approach to convert **non-ascii** dictionary value in **ascii** characters is

```
mydict = {k: unicode(v, errors='ignore').encode('ascii','ignore') for k,v in mydict.iteritems()}
```

Best approach to convert **non-utf-8** dictionary value in **utf-8** characters is

```
mydict = {k: unicode(v, errors='ignore').encode('utf-8','ignore') for k,v in mydict.iteritems()}
```

For more reference read [python unicode documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)