# What is the dictionary comprehension technique and _ in Python code?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the following code, what is the _ for in the loop? Why do we use it? Is it language agnostic?

Also, what is the line

```
dic = {key:value for (key, value) in zip(headers, row) }
```

doing?

```
def parse_file(datafile):
    result = []
    f = open(datafile)

    # loop over the first 11 lines of a file, split() each line
    # and produce a list of stripped() values
    rows = []
    for _ in xrange(11):
        line = f.readline()
        row  = [ value.strip() for value in line.split(',') ] 
        rows.append(row)

    f.close()

    # pop() the first row from rows and use it as headers
    headers = rows.pop(0)

    for row in rows:
        # dic is a dictionary of header-value pairs for each row, 
        # produced by using the builtin zip() function
        # and the dictionary comprehension technique.
        dic = { key:value for (key, value) in zip(headers, row) }

        result.append(dic)        
    return result
```

Comment: The dupe for the other question is [Python Dictionary Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14507591)

Comment: The `_` is just a throw away variable name, you could use any other variable name instead.

Comment: Since the *dictionary comprehension* part has been answered already, you should edit that part out. Or this might get flagged.

Comment: Note that if you're studying this code to learn from it, you might want to find a better model: this code is unpythonic in many ways.