# Make a dictionary from two lists after applying a function

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples

```
keys = [(0,1), (2,1)]
values = [('a','b'), ('c','d')]
```

I want to make a dictionary `dict` that will apply a function `f1` to each

```
dict.keys[i] = keys[i][0], keys[i][i]: f1(keys[i][0],keys[i][1])
```

And for the values of the dictionary, I would like to be tuples

```
dict.values[i] = (f2(values[i][0]), f2(values[i][1]))
```

What is the most efficient way of doing that in one pass in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension).

```
out = {f1(keys[i][0], keys[i][1]):(f2(values[i][0]),f2(values[i][1])) for i in range(len(keys))}
```

If you want to avoid using `range` you can also use `zip` to accomplish the same thing:

```
out = {f1(M[0],M[1]):(f2(N[0]), f2(N[1])) for M,N in zip(keys, values)}
```

And even briefer

```
out = {f1(*M):tuple(map(f2, N)) for M,N in zip(keys, values)}
```

If you're on Python 2.6 or earlier (prior to dictionary comprehensions), you can always use a list comprehension and convert to a dictionary explicitly.

```
out = dict([(f1(*M), tuple(map(f2, N))) for M,N in zip(keys, values)])
```

Comment: Thanks!What is this *M notation at the third solution?

Comment: Is is possible in a single expression to create another dictionary based on the out one without the need to pass again the elements of out? In one loop?

Comment: @curious the * expands the elements in the tuple to be each a separate input to `f1`

Comment: @curious it may be possible depending on what you need but it is likely clearer to break it into two separate statements

Comment: Yes but would it be much faster than 2 loops of a huge list?

Comment: @curious Maybe, but it depends what you are doing inside of the loop.