# Getting list value's length in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Like let's say my list is

```
["Hello","My","Name","is","python"]
```

Can we make this like

```
{"Hello":5,"My":2,"Name":4,"is":2,"python":6}
```

I'm trying to make a programming challenge and finding the words.
But to faster the procces if it finds all lengths so it can check if it is like:
"I am 5 and it is 6 so it can't be me"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) along with [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) for more information about dict-comps.

```
>>> {i:len(i) for i in ["Hello","My","Name","is","python"]}
{'Name': 4, 'python': 6, 'My': 2, 'Hello': 5, 'is': 2}
```

---

Some fun with builtins in Python2, You can do

```
>>> l = ["Hello","My","Name","is","python"]
>>> dict(zip(l,map(len,l)))
{'Name': 4, 'python': 6, 'My': 2, 'Hello': 5, 'is': 2}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank  you for fast answer