# Output dictionary data dynamically from a python for loop

Tags: python

here, I am trying to spell check a txt file. first half of my code outputs original (var word) and corrected, if any, (var spell(word)). my replacement code uses a data structure like `{'zero':'0', 'temp':'bob', 'garbage':'nothing', 'garnvsh': 'garnish'}`. Now I would like to produce the same data structure from the loop dynamically. Can you, please, help me figure it out how to output similar data structure with `var word` and `var spell(word)` with first half of the code?

```
import os, os.path
from textblob import TextBlob
from autocorrect import spell
import fileinput
import json

data = []

with open("input.txt", "r") as my_file:
    for line in my_file.readlines():
        zen = TextBlob(line)
        for word in zen.words:
            word, spell(word)

replacements = {'zero':'0', 'temp':'bob', 'garbage':'nothing', 'garnvsh': 'garnish'}

with open('../input.txt') as infile, open('../output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to [create dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507637/1040597) which its keys are `word` and values are `spell(word)`.

```
my_dict = { word: spell(word) for word in zen.words }
```