# Understanding net_surgery in caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm following the [net_surgery.ipynb](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) example of caffe which explains how to modify the weights of a saved `.caffemodel`. However since I'm quite new to python I can't understand some of the syntax.

Can someone explain me what the 7th line starting with `conv_params = {pr: ...` means in the code example given below? (example is from [net_surgery.ipynb](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) - step 8). Especially what is `pr:`? Is it a key in a (key,value) like structure?

```
# Load the fully convolutional network to transplant the parameters.
net_full_conv = caffe.Net('net_surgery/bvlc_caffenet_full_conv.prototxt', 
                          '../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel',
                          caffe.TEST)
params_full_conv = ['fc6-conv', 'fc7-conv', 'fc8-conv']
# conv_params = {name: (weights, biases)}
conv_params = {pr: (net_full_conv.params[pr][0].data, net_full_conv.params[pr][1].data) for pr in params_full_conv}

for conv in params_full_conv:
    print '{} weights are {} dimensional and biases are {} dimensional'.format(conv, conv_params[conv][0].shape, conv_params[conv][1].shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you are struggling with:

```
conv_params = {pr: (net_full_conv.params[pr][0].data, net_full_conv.params[pr][1].data) for pr in params_full_conv}
```

defines a dictionary `conv_params` with keys `'fc6-conv'`, `'fc7-conv'` and  `'fc8-conv'`.
The construction of the dictionary using `for` statement (`... for pr in ...`) is called 'Dictionary comprehension" and you can find more information about this construct [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14507591/1714410).