# Check for item in multiple lists inside of list

Tags: python, list

Bit of an odd one I've got here...

Basically say I have a list with lists inside of it.

```
ratings = [
    # ''' 1 star '''
    ["Strangers on a Train", "Anchorman", "Saw", "Suicide Squad"],

    # ''' 2 star '''
    ["Shutter Island", "Shaun of the Dead", "Scream", "Indiana Jones"],

    # ''' 3 star'''
    ["Goodfellas", "Mr Bean", "The Ring", "Dark Knight"],

    # ''' 4 star'''
    ["Scarface", "Hot Fuzz", "Nosferatu", "Die Hard"],

    # ''' 5 star'''
    ["Pulp Fiction", "Airplane", "The Omen", "Deadpool"]
]
```

Obviously this is a list of movies, and inside the list is 5 lists giving each of the movies a rating out of 5, although this context is quite useless.

```
def rating():
    if userInfo[7] == "1":
        return range(5)
    elif userInfo[7] == "2":
        return range(2, 5)
    elif userInfo[7] == "3":
        return range(3, 5)
    elif userInfo[7] == "4":
        return range(4, 5)
    else:
        return range(5, 5)
```

Here is a function where essentially a range is returned depending on what minimum rating of film they would like to see is. So say their minimum rating is 4, they will only see films of rating 4 and 5.

say they have a list of movies

```
movies = ["Strangers on a Train", "Anchorman", "Shutter Island",
          "Shaun of the Dead", "Goodfellas", "Mr Bean",
          "Scarface", "Hot Fuzz", "Pulp Fiction", "Airplane"]
```

Now I want to remove all the movies from this list which are not of rating 4 or above.

I tried

```
new = []
for item in movies:
    if item not in in ratings[rating()]:
        new.append(item)
```

but this will not work as I cannot use a range to search through multiple lists inside the big list as it needs to be an integer.

I understand this is a huge post for such a small problem but my brain is dying and I have been trying to do this for hours and I want to sleep but need to do this.

Comment: just use slicing: `ratings[3:]` will give you all movies with a 4 or greater rating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the ratings data is really not optimal for a performant search. So I would make a dictionary with movie names as keys and ratings as values using a dictionary comprehension:

```
movie_rating = {name:i+1 for i,mlist in enumerate(ratings) for name in mlist}
```

(this dictionary can be reused many times)

Then I apply this data to the second list within a list comprehension. Unrated movies get 0 score.

```
print([x for x in movies if movie_rating.get(x,0) >= 4])
```

result:

```
['Scarface', 'Hot Fuzz', 'Pulp Fiction', 'Airplane']
```

This method may not be the shortest but has the advantage of keeping exact rating information, and not "ratings above n".

You can read about [list and dict comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) in this other SO Q & A. The question already explains listcomps very well, and the answer explains dictcomps.

Comment: You are a GODSEND. This definitely works, but I seriously have no idea what you have done, I can't get my head around comprehensions seemingly, Do you have any resources that are useful in helping understand them? If you don't, don't worry about it and thanks for your time :D

Comment: I have edited my post to link to a great SO Q&A, it's very clear there. you could do with classical "for" loops but listcomps are way more elegant, fast to write and fast to execute.