# Summing multiple values of each key in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary, which  looks like this.

```
{ 'item1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  'item2' : [2,3,1],
   .
   .
   .
  'item n' : [4,2,4,3,2]
}
```

Now my requirement is that i want to add the numeric values of this dict & to show it as :-

```
{    'item1' : [21],
     'item2' : [6],
      .
      .
      .
     'item n' : [15]
}
```

I just want the multiple values of each key to be summed up & displayed. FYI, I am using an append function. Below is my code.

```
for row in range(2,sheet2.max_row):
    for column in "D": 
        cell_name = "{}{}".format(column, row)
    for column2 in "P":
        cell_name2 = "{}{}".format(column2,row)
        arrdata2dict.setdefault(sheet2[cell_name].value,[])
        arrdata2dict[sheet2[cell_name].value].append(sheet2[cell_name2].value)
```

Comment: Linking a very similar question: [Sum values in a dict of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42603737/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the dictionary with the sums on-the-fly:

```
Result = dict([(key, sum(values)) for key, values in yourDict.items()])
# or...
Result = {key: sum(values) for key, values in yourDict.items()}
```

Here, the values of the new dictionary will be numbers, but if you *really* need them to be lists, you could enclose the call to `sum` in square brackets: `[sum(values)]`.

Comment: Hi ForceBru, yea i had tried sum() but that did not work, thanks to your this solution, it works

Answer (score 3):

This seems unnecessarily complicated. If you have your input as

```
inpt = { 'item1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'item2' : [2,3,1],
         .
         .
         .
         'item n' : [4,2,4,3,2]
       }
```

you can then use a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) instead:

```
out = {k: [sum(inpt[k])] for k in inpt.keys()}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
items = {'item1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  'item2' : [2,3,1],
  'item3' : [4,2,4,3,2]
}

for key, values in items.items():
    items[key] = sum(values)
```

Comment: Answers that do not include any explanation are often sent to review and can possibly be deleted. Can you provide why this is the correct answer and in how far it improves the questioner's example?