# Sum values in a dict of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

If I have a dictionary such as:

```
my_dict = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [9, -4, 2], "C": [3, 99, 1]}
```

How do I create a new dictionary with sums of the values for each key?

```
result = {"A": 6, "B": 7, "C": 103}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `sum()` function:

```
my_dict = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [9, -4, 2], "C": [3, 99, 1]}

result = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    result[k] = sum(v)

print(result)
```

Or just create a dict with a dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {k: sum(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'A': 6, 'B': 7, 'C': 103}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
def sumDictionaryValues(d):
    new_d = {}
    for i in d:
        new_d[i]= sum(d[i])
    return new_d
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a for loop:

```
new = {}
for key in dict:
    new_d[key]= sum(d[key])
```

new the dictionary having all the summed values

Answer (score -1):

One liners- for the same, just demonstrating some ways to get the expected result,in python3

```py
my_dict = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [9, -4, 2], "C": [3, 99, 1]}
```

1. Using `my_dict.keys()`:- That returns a list containing the `my_dict`'s keys, with dictionary comprehension.

   ```py
   res_dict = {key : sum(my_dict[key]) for key in my_dict.keys()}
   ```

   Note that `my_dict.keys()` produce a list of keys in the dictionary,
   But python dictionary data structure also got an [iterator implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/#dictionary-iterators) to loop
   through keys, (which is faster, but not recommended always) so, this
   will also give same result,

   ```py
   res_dict = {key : sum(my_dict[key]) for key in my_dict}
   ```
2. Using `my_dict.items()`:- That returns a list containing a tuple for each key
   value pair of dictionary, by unpacking them gives a best single line solution for this,

   ```py
   res_dict = {key : sum(val) for key, val in my_dict.items()}
   ```
3. Using `my_dict.values()`:- That returns a list of all the values in the
   dictionary(here the list of each lists),

   *note:- This one is not intended as a direct solution, just for demonstrating the three python methods used to traverse through a dictionary*

   ```py
   res_dict = dict(zip(my_dict.keys(), [sum(val) for val in my_dict.values()]))
   ```

The `zip` function accepts iterators(lists, tuples, strings..), and pairs similar indexed items together and returns a zip object, by using `dict` it is converted back to a dictionary.