# Creating a dictionary from merging a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from using a list that I have to create from one element and a list. Is there an easier way to do this so it is much more efficient?

This is what I have done so far

```
first_element = 1
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

merged_list = []
for item in list2: 
    merged_tuple = (first_element, item)
    merged_list.append(merged_tuple)        

print (merged_list)
>>> [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')]

merged_dict = {value: [(key, value)] for (key, value) in merged_list}
print (merged_dict)
>>> {'a': [(1, 'a')], 'c': [(1, 'c')], 'b': [(1, 'b')]} #desired result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip the intermediate list and just make the mappings directly:

```
first_element = 1
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

merged_dict = {item: [(first_element, item)] for item in list2}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be more pythonic by using a [*dictionary comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
>>> chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> single = 1
>>> 
>>> {key: [(single, key)] for key in chars}
{'a': (1, 'a'), 'c': (1, 'c'), 'b': (1, 'b')}
>>>
```

In this way, you don't need to create `merged_list`, and can skip directly to creating your dictionary.

Comment: @MSeifert Derp. Didn't see that :P But now its fixed ;-)