# How to retain an item in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dictionary `my_dict` and a list of tokens `my_tok` as shown:

```
my_dict = {'tutor': 3,
      'useful': 1,
      'weather': 1,
      'workshop': 3,
      'thankful': 1,
      'puppy': 1}

my_tok = ['workshop',
          'puppy']
```

Is it possible to retain in `my_dict`, only the values present in `my_tok` rather than popping the rest?
i.e., I need to retain only `workshop` and `puppy`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overwrite it like so:

```
my_dict = {k:v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k in my_tok}
```

This is a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) that recreates `my_dict` using only the keys that are present as entries in the `my_tok` list.

As said in the comments, if the number of elemenst in the `my_tok` list is small compaired to the dictionary keys, this solution is not the most efficient one. In that case it would be much better to iterate through the `my_tok` list instead as follows:

```
my_dict = {k:my_dict.get(k, default=None) for k in my_tok}
```

which is more or less what the other answers propose. The only difference is the use of [`.get`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) dictionary method with allows us not to care whether the key is present in the dictionary or not. If it isn't it would be assigned the *default* value.

Comment: I would swap the iterator and the `if` statement since there are only a very limited amount of keys you want to retain an an element check is in general faster on a dictionary.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Very true. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Going over the values from the `my_tok`, and get the results that are within the original dictionary.

```
my_dict = {i:my_dict[i] for i in my_tok}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Create a new copy

You can simply overwrite the original dictionary:

```
new_dic = {token:my_dict[key] for key in my_tok if key in my_dict}
```

Mind however that you construct a **new** dictionary (perhaps you immediately writ it to `my_dict`) but this has implications: other references to the dictionary will not reflect this change.

Since the number of tokens (`my_tok`) are limited, it is probably better to iterate over these tokens and do a contains-check on the dictionary (instead of looping over the tuples in the original dictionary).

## Update the original dictionary

Given you want to let the changes reflect in your original dictionary, you can in a second step you can `.clear()` the original dictionary and `.update()` it accordingly:

```
new_dic = {token:my_dict[key] for key in my_tok if key in my_dict}
my_dict.clear()
my_dict.update(new_dic)
```

Comment: Hi @willem, thanks for the answer, I believe it should be `key` instead of  `token`.

Comment: @Sailesh: you are correct, thanks for pointing that out.