# Python - Make a dictionary by iterating

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntax

I have a list of days and want to create a dictionary that maps first 3 letters of the day to the full name.

I tried:

```
day=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
daydict = dict()
for d in day:    
    daydict.update({d[:3]:d})
```

which gives the desirable result but, then I stumbled upon code which seems more clean.

```
daydict = dict((d[:3],d)for d in day)
```

I don't understand this syntax. Please explain how `dict((d[:3],d)for d in day)` works?

Comment: Even better: `daydict = {d[:3]:d for d in day}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what it does.

`dict((d[:3],d)for d in day)`

For every variable in a `day` as `d` return tuple with 2 values in it. First value is a [:3] symbols taken from d, and the second value is a `d'.
In the end it forms a dictionary from each tuple in the iteration.

more clear

```
days=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
daydict = dict((day[:3],day)for day in days)
```

Comment: so `<some object> for d in days` means return `<some object>` while iterating through days?

Comment: Yeap, your understanding is correct. 
You can do much for with it, like `[x+1 for x in [1,2,3,4]]`

Comment: You might want to add that the construct of `dict((d[:3],d)for d in day)` is a generator expression vs a list comprehension...

Comment: oh, thanks man, I did not know that. I think it deserves another topic.

Answer (score 3):

Better way to achieve this is via using *dict comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> day=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

>>> {d[:3]:d for d in day}
{'Wed': 'Wednesday', 'Sun': 'Sunday', 'Fri': 'Friday', 'Tue': 'Tuesday', 'Mon': 'Monday', 'Thu': 'Thursday', 'Sat': 'Saturday'}
```

---

In your solution, you are creating a `list` of tuples and then type-casting it to `dict`. The value returned by the `[(d[:3],d) for d in day]` (equivalent of *list comprehension* expression to your *generator* expression) will be:

```
[('Mon', 'Monday'), ('Tue', 'Tuesday'), ('Wed', 'Wednesday'), ('Thu', 'Thursday'), ('Fri', 'Friday'), ('Sat', 'Saturday'), ('Sun', 'Sunday')]
```

Let's say this value is store as `my_dict` variable. When you will type-cast it to `dict`, you will get your desired `dict` object as:

```
>>> dict(my_dict)
{'Wed': 'Wednesday', 'Sun': 'Sunday', 'Fri': 'Friday', 'Tue': 'Tuesday', 'Mon': 'Monday', 'Thu': 'Thursday', 'Sat': 'Saturday'}
```

Comment: You beat me by 4 seconds!

Comment: that's not what is asked in the question.

Comment: I don't get the `d[:3]:d for d in day` part. What kind of for loop is this? I tried a for loop that would return `d[:3]:d` but that doesn't work.

Comment: @sudo_dudo It is syntax of *dictionary comprehension*. Check this: [Python Dictionary Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Answer (score 2):

[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) accepts a list (more precisely: an iterator) of tuples (which will become the key-value pair) as argument (there are other options to initialize it); this works:

```
daydict = dict([('Mon', 'Monday'), ('Tue', 'Tuesday'), ('Wed', 'Wednesday'),
                ('Thu', 'Thursday'), ('Fri', 'Friday'), ('Sat', 'Saturday'), 
                ('Sun', 'Sunday')])
```

what you are writing is the shortcut there: a dict-comprehension (you don't create the full list just an iterator for your key-value pairs; the dict constructor iterates over them on the go.

python now supports a more compact version of this:

```
daydict = {d[:3]: d for d in day}
```

Comment: dictcomp is probably faster than creating from tuples.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: i briefly had a look at the disassembly of both version: the dictcomp version is shorter at least. did not do any benchmarking though...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How is dictcomp faster than creating tuples? From my understanding thay both are doing the same job. is it because its a generator function ?

Comment: because creating a tuple allocates some memory for the temporary tuple object. dictcomp is more natural if the tuples don't already exist. It's the allocation that's costly, not the part done by the dictionary.

Comment: Adding to Jean's explanation. Generator expression involves 2 operations. 1. To create a list of tuples. 2. To type-cast the entire list to dict. Where as in dict comprehension you will be creating dict at the first place