# blackjack -- dictionary output

Tags: python

```
def get_card_value(s):
    s = ' '
    cards ={'A':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
    for s in cards.keys():
        return cards.values(s)
    else:
        raise ValueError("No card found")

get_card_value(A)
```

I am making a blackjack game and am stuck on the first part where I need to define a function that gets the integer points for the card `s`. So input is the string value of card and the output should be the integer score of the card.

Can anyone help with what I've written?

Comment: I'd take a close look at all the [different operations dictionaries support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). Compare those with what you've written. Do you see anything in those operations that might work better for what you are trying to do?

Comment: One thing to consider is that you are overwriting the value of `s` by assigning it an empty string.

Comment: @José: Actually it's assigning a string with one space character in it to `s`—but otherwise the point you make is accurate. In addition, the card rank argument passed to the function should be a string: i.e. `get_card_value('A')` and the membership test should just be `for s in cards:`.

Comment: Hint: what's `cards['A']` going to equal in the function?

Comment: It says name 'A' is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing values in a dictionary is not done via the `values()` method, but rather via bracket-notation (eg. `my_dictionary[key]`). See [`d[key]` in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

---

Additionally, you could try just making a `dict` instead of a full-blown function:

```
>>> card_points = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5':5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10}
>>> card_points['A']
1
>>> card_points['5']
5
```

If you *need* it to be a function you can easily wrap this dictionary:

```
def get_card_value(s):
    card_points = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5':5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10}
    try:
        return card_points[s]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("No card found")
```

Note: `KeyError` is the exception raised when trying to access a non-existent key in a dictionary, so if we encounter one of those, we can choose to instead raise our custom `ValueError` exception.

---

Or if you want to get fancy (read: save some keystrokes):

```
>>> card_points = dict({str(i): i for i in range(2, 11)}, A=1, J=10, Q=10, K=10)
```

In the snippet above, `{str(i): i for i in range(2, 11)}` uses a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) to create a dictionary mapping string values for the integers 2-10 to their numeric values. For the non-numeric cards, I pass them in as [keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python). Luckily, [python's built-in `dict` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) can handle both of these at once!

So if you are just beginning you might want to use the first form rather than leverages a bunch of python's advanced features :)

Comment: @Cindy see the `get_card_values` code block for how to wrap it in a function

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing a dictionary outside the function but if you want it inside try this

```
def get_card_value(s): 
    cards = {'A':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10} 
    if s in cards:
        return cards[s]
    else: 
        raise ValueError("No card found")
```

and then try it like this

```
print(get_card_value("4"))
print(get_card_value("Y"))
```

Keys in dictionary are strings so you have to use function get_card_value using strings