# Slippy Maps on Python Tkinter Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, dictionary, tkinter

I am making a GUI game. The game has a central character moving on a map, and I am attempting to find a way to make it so that the character can move around on the map quickly. I have heard talk of Slippy Maps, but only on Windows, and I unfortunately use a Mac OSx. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.right = False
        self.left = False
        self.up = False
        self.down = False
        self.grid()
        self.px = 16
        self.py = 8
        self.a = "green"
        self.b = 'blue'
        self.c = "green"
        self.line1 = {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line2 = {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.c,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line3 = {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line4 = {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line5 = {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line6 = {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.b,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line7 = {1:self.b,2:self.b,3:self.b,4:self.b,5:self.b,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line8 = {1:self.b,2:self.b,3:self.b,4:self.b,5:self.b,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line9 = {1:self.b,2:self.b,3:self.b,4:self.b,5:self.b,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line10= {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.b,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line11= {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line12= {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line13= {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line14= {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.line15= {1:self.a,2:self.a,3:self.a,4:self.a,5:self.a,6:self.a,7:self.a,8:self.a,9:self.a,10:self.a,11:self.a,12:self.a,13:self.a,14:self.a,15:self.a,16:self.a,17:self.a,18:self.a,19:self.a,20:self.a,21:self.a,22:self.a,23:self.a,24:self.a,25:self.a,26:self.a,27:self.a,28:self.a,29:self.a,30:self.a,31:self.a,32:self.a,33:self.a,34:self.a,35:self.a,36:self.a,37:self.a,38:self.a,39:self.a,40:self.a,41:self.a,42:self.a,43:self.a,44:self.a,45:self.a,46:self.a,47:self.a,48:self.a,49:self.a,50:self.a,51:self.a,52:self.a,53:self.a,54:self.a,55:self.a,56:self.a,57:self.a,58:self.a,59:self.a,60:self.a,61:self.a,62:self.a,63:self.a,64:self.a,65:self.a,66:self.a,67:self.a,68:self.a,69:self.a,70:self.a,71:self.a,72:self.a,73:self.a,74:self.a,75:self.a,76:self.a,77:self.a,78:self.a,79:self.a,80:self.a,81:self.a,82:self.a,83:self.a,84:self.a,85:self.a,86:self.a,87:self.a,88:self.a,89:self.a,90:self.a,91:self.a,92:self.a,93:self.a,94:self.a,95:self.a,96:self.a,97:self.a,98:self.a,99:self.a,100:self.a}
        self.map = [self.line1,self.line2,self.line3,self.line4,self.line5,self.line6,self.line7,self.line8,self.line9,self.line10,self.line11,self.line12,self.line13,self.line14,self.line15]
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        Text(self, width = 20, height = 1, wrap = WORD).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3,sticky = W)
        y = 0
        q = 1
        s = 0
        self.a = "yellow"
        for i in self.map:
            if q == self.py:
                s = 1
            w = 0
            for x in range(31):
                if self.px-15 <= 0:
                    x += 1
                else:
                    x += (self.px-15)
                if s == 1 and x == self.px:
                    Label(self, text = "  /  ", bg = "navajo white", fg = "saddle brown",font = ("Times", 20)).grid(row = y, column = w+3)
                    s = 0
                else:
                    Label(self, text = "  /  ", bg = i[x], fg = i[x], font = ("Times", 20)).grid(row = y, column = w+3)
                w += 1
            y += 1
            q += 1
    def keyPressed(self,event):
        if event.keysym == 'Escape':
            root.destroy()
        elif event.keysym == 'Right':
            self.right = True
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            self.left = True
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            self.up = True
        elif event.keysym == 'Down':
            self.down = True
    def keyReleased(self,event):
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            self.right = False
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            self.left = False
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            self.up = False
        elif event.keysym == 'Down':
            self.down = False
    def task(self):
        if self.right:
            self.mr()
        elif self.left:
            self.ml()
        elif self.up:
            self.mu()
        elif self.down:
            self.md()
        root.after(20,self.task)
    def mr(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        self.px += 1
        self.create_widgets()
    def ml(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        self.px -= 1
        self.create_widgets()
    def mu(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        self.py -= 1
        self.create_widgets()
    def md(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        self.py += 1
        self.create_widgets()
root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.bind_all('<Key>', app.keyPressed)
root.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', app.keyReleased)
root.after(20, app.task)
root.title("RPG")
root.geometry("10000x100000")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have no idea about slippery maps or what you are asking, but please use `self.map = [{key: self.a for key in xrange(1, 101)} for _ in xrange(15)]` instead of writing all those dictionaries by hand. Then you can change manually your values like `self.map[1][3] = self.c` etc. Changing manually is not ideal also, but at least better than this approach.

Comment: You can read more on dictionary comprehension from here: [Python Dictionary Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)