# Rename groupname title pandas

Tags: python, bash, pandas

I print the report on terminal using below python code

```
print(kf.groupby(level='ErrorCode').apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()))
```

to get

```
ErrorCode  ResponseType        
0          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
1          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
dtype: float64
```

But the ErrorCode 0,1 have to be mapped to a different number.
That mapping can be written in a file in any format.
Currently I can write mapping file as

```
0 10.0.0.0
1 10.0.0.1
2 10.2.0.1
```

Format of above can be changed.
Is there a way to replace grouped value output by mapped values.
Final output would be like

```
ErrorCode           ResponseType        
0  10.0.0.0         CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
                    TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
1  10.0.0.1         CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
                    TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
dtype: float64
```

It is even ok, if this can be done in bash, but alignment should be readable.

If this is very tricky, then I would simply make ErrorCode column values to change according to mapping file (but I think that too is not a very good approach)

Update1: Similarly I have `data.groupby([data['ErrorCode'], pd.Grouper(freq='1500T')])['latency'].describe().unstack(0)`

and my output is

```
ErrorCode                      0               1
Time_req                                        
2017-03-08 count      111.000000      111.000000
           mean    251509.738739   357710.729730
           std     250469.755466   795885.356352
           min     104877.000000   111343.000000
           25%     132616.000000   131953.000000
           50%     160899.000000   163100.000000
           75%     261440.000000   279448.000000
           max    2071299.000000  8039122.000000
```

But I need to map ErrorCode using a dictionary named myd
which is `myd={0: '0 172.19.13.51', 1: '1 172.19.13.51'}` such that output is something like below

```
ErrorCode         0 172.19.13.51  1 172.19.13.51
Time_req                                        
2017-03-08 count      111.000000      111.000000
           mean    251509.738739   357710.729730
           std     250469.755466   795885.356352
           min     104877.000000   111343.000000
           25%     132616.000000   131953.000000
           50%     160899.000000   163100.000000
           75%     261440.000000   279448.000000
           max    2071299.000000  8039122.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) for replace all values from `keys` of `dict` to `values`:

```
d = {0: '10.0.0.0', 1: '10.0.0.1',2: '10.2.0.1'}
df = df.rename(index=d)

print (df)
ErrorCode  ResponseType        
10.0.0.0   CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
10.0.0.1   CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

If need keys and values together:

```
d = {0: '10.0.0.0', 1: '10.0.0.1',2: '10.2.0.1'}
d = {k:str(k) + ' ' + v for k, v in d.items()}
df = df.rename(index=d)

print (df)
ErrorCode   ResponseType        
0 10.0.0.0  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
            TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
1 10.0.0.1  CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.7207
            TRADE_CONFIRM           0.2792
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: how to understand / read `d = {k:str(k) + ' ' + v for k, v in d.items()}` I know it changes the key to ( key value concat )

Comment: it loop each value of dist and concanecate key and value of each item of dict and get it to value and output is another dict.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14507637/2901002) explain it better, maybe also [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/comprehensions/738/dictionary-comprehensions#t=201703171317054989916)

Comment: II think only need change `index` to `columns` - `df = df.rename(columns=d)`