# issue with movie.py with renaming script

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I have a lot of videos stored in different subfolders. All the videos have weird file names like `f4vd5sd1b5dsd41s415d`. And I have a text file where there are the correct file names of each file. To know which video goes with which title, I added the file duration of the video I want to correspond with the title, so in my text file there is:

in line 1: the name of video 1

in line 2: the video length of video 1

in line 3: the name of video 2

in line 4: the video length of video 2

To better explain it here's some work I did manually:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

My script is:

```
import os
import shutil
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

# parses the renaming rules described in your text file
# returns a dictionary where:
#    key represents the duration to match
#    value represents the name to rename the video file to
def parse_rules(path):
  with open(path) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    rules = { lines[i+1]: lines[i] for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)}
  return rules # structure { duration: rename_to, ... }

# gets the duration of the video file
def duration(file):
  return VideoFileClip(file).duration

 # determines whether the durations are close enough to   be considered similar
def is_close_enough(duration1, duration2):
  return duration1 == duration2

# makes a copy of source file according to the renaming rules specified and puts the resulting file in the destination folder 
def rename_by_rules(src_file, dst_dir, rules):
  for k, rename_to in rules.items():
    if is_close_enough(k, duration(src_file)):
      shutil.copy2(src_file, os.path.join(dst_dir, rename_to)) 

# begins renaming your video files matched by duration according to the rules in your text file
rules = parse_rules('<replace with your text file>')
for base, dirs, files in os.walk('<replace with your source director>'):
  for file in files:
    if file.endswith('mp4'):
      rename_by_rules(os.path.join(base, file), '<replace   by dest dir>', rules)
```

My Python version is 3.6.1 and I have Windows 7 64bit. The traceback call is:

```
"F:\Dossier Gros Nain\Python\Python 3.6.1\python.exe" "F:/Dossier Gros Nain/Pluralsight courses/1h Fundamentals of Arnold for Maya/Videos dupli - Copie/supreme script of death.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Dossier Gros Nain/Pluralsight courses/1h Fundamentals of Arnold for Maya/Videos dupli - Copie/supreme script of death.py", line 45, in <module>
    rules)
  File "F:/Dossier Gros Nain/Pluralsight courses/1h Fundamentals of Arnold for Maya/Videos dupli - Copie/supreme script of death.py", line 33, in rename_by_rules
    if is_close_enough (k, duration (src_file)):
  File "F:/Dossier Gros Nain/Pluralsight courses/1h Fundamentals of Arnold for Maya/Videos dupli - Copie/supreme script of death.py", line 20, in duration
    return VideoFileClip (file).duration
  File "F:\Dossier Gros Nain\Python\Python 3.6.1\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 81, in __init__
    fps_source=fps_source)
  File "F:\Dossier Gros Nain\Python\Python 3.6.1\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "F:\Dossier Gros Nain\Python\Python 3.6.1\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 103, in initialize
    self.proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
  File "F:\Dossier Gros Nain\Python\Python 3.6.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 594, in __init__
    _cleanup()
  File "F:\Dossier Gros Nain\Python\Python 3.6.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 205, in _cleanup
    res = inst._internal_poll(_deadstate=sys.maxsize)
  File "F:\Dossier Gros Nain\Python\Python 3.6.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 1025, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] Descripteur non valide

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is it a problem with movie.py? If yes, how could I remove it? Could I use ffprobe if nothing else works?

Comment: You probably have 2 (or more) videos with roughly the same length, so a video gets renamed, but then your loop keeps going and tries to rename the same file a 2nd time. Add a `break` after `shutil.copy2(...)`. Or better yet, find the video name with the best matching duration.

Comment: with break it didn't work either and how could I find the video name with the best matching duration ? and yes there is indeed one file with the same duration

Comment: You want to find the duration with the least difference to the video's duration, so something like `min(rules, key=lambda rule_duration:abs(rule_duration-video_duration))`.

Comment: where should I put that code in please ? If I put it in it says that duration have no attribute. here is my traceback : https://codeshare.io/2pAvqD

Comment: Video formats usually include a header with various data. You could use this data to uniquely identify each file, so - even if two movies have the exact same duration - you could treat them separately.