# How to create a dictionary of key : column_name and value : unique values in column in python from a dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary of key:value pairs where key is the column name of a dataframe and value will be a list containing all the unique values in that column.Ultimately I want to be able to filter out the key_value pairs from the dict based on conditions. This is what I have been able to do so far:

```
for col in col_list[1:]:
    _list = []
    _list.append(footwear_data[col].unique())
    list_name = ''.join([str(col),'_list'])

product_list = ['shoe','footwear']
color_list = []
size_list = []
```

Here product,color,size are all column names and the dict keys should be named accordingly like color_list etc.
Ultimately I will need to access each key:value_list in the dictionary.
Expected output:

```
KEY              VALUE
color_list :    ["red","blue","black"]
size_list:  ["9","XL","32","10 inches"]
```

Can someone please help me regarding this?A snapshot of the data is attached.[image: data_frame]

Comment: can you add your dataframe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `DataFrame` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["Women", "Slip on", 7, "Black", "Clarks"], ["Women", "Slip on", 8, "Brown", "Clarcks"], ["Women", "Slip on", 7, "Blue", "Clarks"]], columns= ["Category", "Sub Category", "Size", "Color", "Brand"])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Category Sub Category  Size  Color    Brand
0    Women      Slip on     7  Black   Clarks
1    Women      Slip on     8  Brown  Clarcks
2    Women      Slip on     7   Blue   Clarks
```

You can convert your DataFrame into dict and create your new dict when mapping the the columns of the DataFrame, like this example:

```
new_dict = {"color_list": list(df["Color"]), "size_list": list(df["Size"])}
# OR:
#new_dict = {"color_list": [k for k in df["Color"]], "size_list": [k for k in df["Size"]]}

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'color_list': ['Black', 'Brown', 'Blue'], 'size_list': [7, 8, 7]}
```

In order to have a unique values, you can use `set` like this example:

```
new_dict = {"color_list": list(set(df["Color"])), "size_list": list(set(df["Size"]))}
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'color_list': ['Brown', 'Blue', 'Black'], 'size_list': [8, 7]}
```

Or, like what @Ami Tavory said in his answer, in order to have the whole unique keys and values from your DataFrame, you can simply do this:

```
new_dict = {k:list(df[k].unique()) for k in df.columns}
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Brand': ['Clarks', 'Clarcks'],
 'Category': ['Women'],
 'Color': ['Black', 'Brown', 'Blue'],
 'Size': [7, 8],
 'Sub Category': ['Slip on']}
```

Comment: This works with a small addition of unique such as:"color_list": [k for k in dict(footwear_data)["Color"].unique(). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can do simply `footwear_data["Color"].unique()`  if `footwear` is your DataFrame.

Comment: Look, at my new updates. I've added many manners to have the same output. Take the one that fills your needs.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create a dictionary of key:value pairs where key is the column name of a dataframe and value will be a list containing all the unique values in that column.

You could use a simple [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) for that.

Say you start with

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1], 'b': [1, 4, 5]})
```

Then the following comprehension solves it:

```
>>> {c: list(df[c].unique()) for c in df.columns}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [1, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may need `set` instead of list. Probably at this piece of code, you might add `set` to get the unique values of the given list.

```
for col in col_list[1:]:
    _list = []
    _list.append(footwear_data[col].unique())
    list_name = ''.join([str(col),'_list'])
    list_name = set(list_name)
```

Sample of usage

```
>>> a_list = [7, 8, 7, 9, 10, 9]
>>> set(a_list)
    {8, 9, 10, 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how i did it let me know if it helps

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/csv/file")

colList = list(df)
dic = {}
for x in colList:
    _list = []
    _list.append(list(set(list(df[x]))))
    list_name = ''.join([str(x), '_list'])
    dic[str(x)+"_list"] = _list


print dic
```

Output:

```
{'Color_list': [['Blue', 'Orange', 'Black', 'Red']], 'Size_list': [['9', '8', '10 inches', 'XL', '7']], 'Brand_list': [['Clarks']], 'Sub_list': [['SO', 'FOR']], 'Category_list': [['M', 'W']]}
```

MyCsv File

```
Category,Sub,Size,Color,Brand
W,SO,7,Blue,Clarks
W,SO,7,Blue,Clarks
W,SO,7,Black,Clarks
W,SO,8,Orange,Clarks
W,FOR,8,Red,Clarks
M,FOR,9,Black,Clarks
M,FOR,10 inches,Blue,Clarks
M,FOR,XL,Blue,Clarks
```