# Relabeling Nodes of a graph in networkx

Tags: networkx

I am trying to process the graph given in wiki-Vote.txt (https://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-Vote.html). There are 7115 nodes with id ranging from 3 to 8297. I want to relabel the nodes from 0 to 7114. I checked the mappings in relabel_nodes() but still could not solve the problem. Please suggest. thanks

Comment: What _is_ the problem? How does it manifest? (What happened when you tried to check the mappings in `relabel_nodes()`?) What have you tried to do in response to that?

If it's a home/coursework exercise, it'd be appreciated if you indicated it.

Comment: the mappings seems to be either specified explicitly or defined for a contiguous range. how can the mapping be defined for my case? Its not a homework. thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  I'm not sure what you mean by: "I checked the mappings in relabel_nodes() but still could not solve the problem."

Comment: @Joel, Let a graph be 2--3, 5---7, 3---5. I want to change the labels to 0--1, 2--3, 1--2. How to define the mapping here. We can explicitly define it for this example. But how to do it for a large graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**edit**
I'm not sure if it's new, but my original answer didn't mention
`nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G, first_label=0, ordering='default', label_attribute=None)`.  So for a given graph `G`, you can do
`H=nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)`.  This doesn't guarantee that the order is the same as in `G`.  You can have the original label be stored in `H` if you call `H=nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G, label_attribute='original_name')`.  You can guarantee that the order is the same as in `G`, by setting `ordering=sorted(G.nodes())`.

**original answer**

Given a graph `G` with some set of nodes, the simplest thing would be

```
mapping = {old_label:new_label for new_label, old_label in enumerate(G.nodes())}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
```

This will create a dictionary `mapping` whose keys are the old labels and whose values are their new labels (read up on [dictionary comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507637/2966723)).  The ordering of the new labels is given by the order that `G.nodes()` returns the values (which you can't control).  The new graph `H` has the node labels changed.

If you want a specific order, you need to sort G.nodes() appropriately.  So you can do

```
nodelist = G.nodes()
nodelist.sort()
mapping = {old_label:new_label for new_label, old_label in enumerate(nodelist)}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
```

which would have them sorted in numerical order (or alphabetical order if the node names are strings).  If you want some other custom order, you'll have to figure out how to sort nodelist.