# Assign edge weights from Euclidean distance between nodes

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm creating a complete graph with 50 randomly created nodes. Each node is defined as a Cartesian coordinate as follows:

```
n = 50
V = []
V=range(n)

random.seed()

pos = {i:(random.randint(0,500),random.randint(0,500)) for i in V}
```

I need to assign the Euclidean distance between each node as the edge weight corresponds to that pair of nodes.

I have already defined the Euclidean distance between two nodes as follows:

```
points = []
positions = []
for i in pos:
    points.append(pos[i])
    positions.append(i)
    positions.append(pos[i])

def distance(points, i, j):
    dx = points[i][0] - points[j][0]
    dy = points[i][1] - points[j][1]
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

I tried assigning Euclidean distance as their weight as follows:

```
for u in V:
    for v in V:
        weights = distance(points, u,v)

G = nx.complete_graph(n)
for e in G.edges():
   weights[e] = distance(points, e[0],e[1])
```

But this returns the following error.

```
    weights[e] = distance(points, e[0],e[1])

TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment
```

Can someone suggest me a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that after

```
for u in V:
    for v in V:
        weights = distance(points, u,v)
```

`weights` is a float (the distance of the last pair compared).

Now you do

```
for e in G.edges():
    weights[e] = distance(points, e[0],e[1])
```

You're assigning the `e`th item of the float `weights` to be something.  Not allowed.

What I think you want is

```
for u,v in G.edges():
    G[u][v]['distance'] = distance(points, u, v)
```

As a note, rather than having `points` defined, I would make the nodes be a tuple of cartesian coordinates.  See [Relabeling Nodes of a graph in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606176/relabeling-nodes-of-a-graph-in-networkx)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Joel mentioned, here is the code that works.

```
import random
import networkx as nx
import math
import itertools    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 50
V = []
V=range(n)

random.seed()

pos = {i:(random.randint(0,500),random.randint(0,500)) for i in V}
points = []
positions = []
for i in pos:
    points.append(pos[i])
    positions.append(i)
    positions.append(pos[i])

def distance(points, i, j):
    dx = points[i][0] - points[j][0]
    dy = points[i][1] - points[j][1]
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

G=nx.empty_graph(n)

for u in V:
    for v in V:
        wt = distance(points, u,v)
        G.add_edge(u,v,weight = wt)

nx.draw(G,pos)
edges,weights = zip(*nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight').items())
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='k', edgelist=edges, edge_color=weights, width=1, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
```

[Edges colored by edgeweights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbt3F.png)