# how this for loop works in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to python. Please anyone help me to understand this statement of python. How it will work ?

```
  {x: {y: 0. for y in myClass.features} for x in myClass.items}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code preceding this line of code

Comment: It's not a for-loop, but a (nested) dict comprehension. See e.g.: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what it do is to create a nested dictionary with all values equal to 0.0

```
class myClassrino:
    def __init__(self):
        self.features=[1,2,3,4,5]
        self.items=[3,4,5,6]

myClass=myClassrino()
output={x: {y: 0. for y in myClass.features} for x in myClass.items}
print(output)
```

Output is:

```
{3: {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0}, 4: {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0}, 5: {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0}, 6: {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0}}
```

Feel free to post anything you are still unclear..

Comment: thank you. y : 0 here : is equal to assignment operator  or what ?

Comment: @y : 0 equal to d[y]=0, you can check it out here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Consider accept the answer by clicking the check on the left of question, it will remove the this from review queue, save other moderators time and distribute the points around.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try.

```
{x: {y: 0. for y in [1,2,3]} for x in ['a','b','c']}
```

=

```
{'a': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}, 'b': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}, 'c': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}}
```

Then ones can have some feeling about it from the output.

---

To be easier, you can decompose it:

```
{y: 0. for y in [1,2,3]}
```

=

```
{1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}
```

after substitution, we have

```
{x: {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0} for x in ['a','b','c']}
```

final answer =

```
{'a': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}, 'b': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}, 'c': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}}
```

---

Now you only need to replace

```
[1,2,3] and ['a','b','c']
```

to

```
myClass.features and myClass.items
```

Both are implicitly declared by defining them.

---

Sorry for my poor expression.

Comment: Thank you. You explained very well