# Create dictionary from two numpy arrays

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following two numpy arrays:

```
a = array([400., 403., 406.]);
b = array([0.2,0.55,0.6]);
```

Now I would like to create a dictionary where the array a acts as keys and b as corresponding values:

```
dic = { 
  400: 0.2,
  403: 0.55,
  406: 0.6
}
```

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: `dict(zip(a,b))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a quick for loop with zipped iterables.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([400., 403., 406.]);
b = np.array([0.2,0.55,0.6]);
dict = {}
for A, B in zip(a, b):
    dict[A] = B

print(dict)
# {400.0: 0.2, 403.0: 0.55, 406.0: 0.6}
```

Comment: The same using [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507637/2641825): `{A: B for A, B in zip(a, b)}`

Comment: Minor comment on this answer: it is generally bad practice to use reserved type names such as `dict` as variable names.