# how to filter the dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, filter

output the dictionary:

```
{u'person': [(95, 11, 474, 466)],
 u'chair': [(135, 410, 276, 587)], 
 u'book': [(127, 380, 161, 396)]}
```

I need only `u'person': [(95, 11, 474, 466)]`

how to filter this?

this is part of a dictionary in my code:

```
detected_objects = {}
# analyze all worthy detections
for x in range(worthy_detections):

    # capture the class of the detected object
    class_name = self._categories[int(classes[0][x])]

    # get the detection box around the object
    box_objects = boxes[0][x]

    # positions of the box are between 0 and 1, relative to the size of the image
    # we multiply them by the size of the image to get the box location in pixels
    ymin = int(box_objects[0] * height)
    xmin = int(box_objects[1] * width)
    ymax = int(box_objects[2] * height)
    xmax = int(box_objects[3] * width)

    if class_name not in detected_objects:
        detected_objects[class_name] = []


    detected_objects[class_name].append((ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax))
detected_objects = detected_objects
print detected_objects
```

please help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a substitute to reading the official documentation.

Comment: first of all, I am a beginner in python, then I didn't see the same my case in official documentation, thank you

Comment: If you're a beginner (no problem with being a beginner, we've all been - and still are - beginners), then the first thing you want to do - and that's part of what's expected _before_ you post a question here - is to read the doc and do the official tutorial (when there's one, but that's most often the case nowadays at least for languages and frameworks).  If you had done the official Python tutorial, you would have found out how to get a specific key from a dict, and generalizing from there how to filter a dict based on specific key(s).

Comment: thank you so much for those recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply copy the keys you are interested in over into a new dict:

```
detected_objects  = {u'person': [(95, 11, 474, 466)], 
                     u'chair': [(135, 410, 276, 587)], 
                     u'book': [(127, 380, 161, 396)]}

keys_to_keep = {u'person'}

# dictionary comprehension
filtered_results = { k:v for k,v in detected_objects.items() if k in keys_to_keep}
print  filtered_results
```

Output:

```
{u'person': [(95, 11, 474, 466)]}
```

See [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)