# How to build a variable dynamically by iterating through for loop in python

Tags: python, string, variables

I have a bunch of variables as below.Now, I want to build a variable dynamically as below by iterating through for loop but surprisingly this won't work as .format can only be implemented for strings. Could anyone share your thoughts like how can this be implemented in Py? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
build_a="123"
build_b="456"
build_c="789"

build_src = ['a','b','c']
build_list = {}

for word in build_src:
    build_list[word] = build_{word}.format(word=word)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are doing this instead of using a dictionary?

Comment: build_a,build_b,build_c are variables which have huge strings....the example I have posted is simple one

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The question remains. Use a dictionary, it exists to solve problems like this.

Comment: Do not use dynamic variables. *Just use a container*, likes a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: The syntax you show here is incorrect. The format mini language works only on strings. `build_{word}.format(foo)` will cause s syntax error. Sure there are unholy hacks  to achieve what you want (eval and exec based incantations come to mind). But as others have pointed out, what you need is a suitable data structure and a dictionary is fine for this case.  On the other hand, if you are exploring code generation or the like, simply build a string of the form you want then call on exec to bring ye beast to life.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary might be much better suited for what you're trying to achieve.

```
builds = {'a': "123", 'b': "456", 'c': "789"}
build_src = ['a','b','c']
build_list = {}
for word in build_src:
    build_list[word] = builds.get(word, None)
print build_list
```

Output:
`{'a': '123', 'c': '789', 'b': '456'}`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want:

```
build_src = ['a','b','c']
build_list = {}

for word in build_src:
    build_list[word] = 'build_'+word.format(word=word)
print(build_list)
```

output:

```
{'a': 'build_a', 'b': 'build_b', 'c': 'build_c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this :

```
build_a="123"
build_b="456"
build_c="789"

build_src = ['a','b','c']
build_list = {}

for word in build_src:
    globals()['build_new_var%s' % word] = word
```

it will give you what you want, something like this :

```
print(build_new_var_a)
print(build_new_var_b)
```

and the output will be :

```
a
b
```

but using dictionary would be a better solution , but if you need this for a particular reason you can do this too .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in most of the answers a `dict` is the solution to your problems.

## Option 1: through a pair of `list`s thanks to `zip`

In this case the `tuple` is formed by the `zip` function which returns an *iterator* which is *consumed* by the `dict`. This *iterator* merges the 2 `list`s by preserving the item's index.

**Note: if you are planing to use 2 `list`s with different length you might be interested in having a look to [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).**

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [123, 456, 789]

build_src = zip(keys, values)
build_list = dict(build_src)
```

## Option 2: using `dict` comprehension

You can use a [`dict` comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) in case you want to explicitly show the loop during the `dict` construction process.

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [123, 456, 789]

build_src = zip(keys, values)
build_list = {key: val for key, val in build_src}
```