# How to write an expression returning a dict with some elements replaced?

Tags: python

Can one write a concise expression that evaluates to an *existing* dictionary except with some of the elements replaced (modified, substituted)?
Example:

```
a = {'x': 3, 'y': 8}
```

I'd like to write an expression that evaluates to a dict with the 'x' element's value incremented by one:

```
{'x': 4, 'y': 8}
```

I don't want to modify `a` (as in `a['x'] += 1`); I want to treat `a` as immutable. I could do this:

```
a = {'x': 3, 'y': 8}
a_copy = a.copy()
a_copy['x'] += 1
```

then reference `a_copy`. But is there a more succinct approach that doesn't require an additional variable? (I need to reference the resultant dictionary only once.) Performance isn't a concern.

[Dictionary comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) can be used to generate a *new* dictionary, but I want an expression that returns a slight variation of an *existing* dictionary.

Comment: `a_copy = {k: v+1 if k=='x' else v for k, v in a.items()}` .. looking for a dupe

Comment: i will say, your method is pretty small and clear in its intents, and readable too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)   and [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension, only incrementing values for the keys you want to increment

```
#I took the keys in a list if you want to increment more keys
keys_to_incr = ['x']
a = {'x': 3, 'y': 8}

#Increment value if key falls in keys_to_incr, else leave value as0is
a_copy = {k: v+1 if k in keys_to_incr else v for k, v in a.items()}
print(a_copy)
```

The output will be

```
{'x': 4, 'y': 8}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of obscure but does the job, only works since Python 3.5:

```
a = {'x': 3, 'y': 8}
a_copy = {**a, 'x': a['x'] + 1}
print(a_copy)
# {'x': 4, 'y': 8}
```

A better approach is using a comprehension:

```
a_copy = {k: v + 1 if k == 'x' else v for k, v in a.items()}
```