# Python: Comparing value overlap between keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a `dict` like this:

```
dict = defaultdict(list, {'a': [['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'],
                               ['1', '3', 'A', 'dog']], 
                          'b': [['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'],
                               ['1', '3', 'A', 'dog']],
                          'c': [['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'],
                               ['2', '2', 'A', 'snake'],
                               ['2', '2', 'A', 'bird']]}
```

I'd like to get all pairwise comparisons for overlapping values using the *full list* for each value. (Every position in the value list must match for it to be considered a match between keys)

Since `a` and `b` share `['1', '3', 'A', 'dog']` and `c` doesn't, `a/b: ['1', '3', 'A', 'dog']`.

`a`, `b`, `c`, all share `['1', '2', 'A', 'cat']`, `a/b/c: ['1', '2', 'A', 'cat']`.

Only `c` has `['2', '2', 'A', 'snake']`, so `c: ['2', '2', 'A', 'snake']`

Preferred output is a dictionary combining the above, something like

```
combine_dict = {'a/b': ['1', '3', 'A', 'dog'], 'a/b/c': ['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'], 'c': [['2', '2', 'A', 'snake'], ['2', '2', 'A', 'bird']]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
d = {'a': [['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'], ['1', '3', 'A', 'dog']], 'b': [['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'], ['1', '3', 'A', 'dog']], 'c': [['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'], ['2', '2', 'A', 'snake'], ['2', '2', 'A', 'bird']]}
new_d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for a, b in d.items():
  for i in b:
     new_d[tuple(i)].append(a)


new_r = collections.defaultdict(list)
for a, b in new_d.items():
   new_r['/'.join(b)].append(list(a))

new_result = {a:b[0] if len(b) == 1 else b for a, b in new_r.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a/b/c': ['1', '2', 'A', 'cat'], 'a/b': ['1', '3', 'A', 'dog'], 'c': [['2', '2', 'A', 'snake'], ['2', '2', 'A', 'bird']]}
```

Comment: Could you explain `new_result = {'/'.join(b):list(a) for a, b in new_d.items()}` a little more? I tried to write it out as `for a, b in combination_dict.items():
    combination_list = '/'.join(b):list(a)` to understand what's going on but that code has invalid syntax.

Comment: @Liquidity `{'/'.join(b):list(a) for a, b in new_d.items()}` is a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension). Please see my recent edit, as I added code for the creation of `new_result` in a more readable way

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I think I've found a problem - if there are more than two values, this only saves the last. I updated my example so that `c` should output `'c': ['2', '2', 'A', 'snake'], ['2', '2', 'A', 'bird']`, but using your code only outputs `'c': ['2', '2', 'A', 'bird']`. You answered the original example fine, I should've been clearer that I wanted all values saved even if more than one was shared or not shared! Should I open that as a new question?