# Pythonic way to define Dictionary keys with items in a list

Tags: python

Is there a pythonic way to use items in a list to define a dictionary's key and values?

For example, I can do it with:

```
s = {}
a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']

for a in aa:
   s['text_%s' %a] = 'stuff %s' %a

In [27]: s
Out[27]: {'text_aa': 'stuff aa', 'text_bb': 'stuff bb', 'text_cc': 'stuff cc'}
```

I wanted to know if its possible to iterate over the list with list comprehension or some other trick.

something like:

```
s[('text_' + a)] = ('stuff_' + a) for a in aa
```

thanks!

Comment: You can do `{f'text_{a}': f'stuff_{a}' for a in aa}` (from Python 3.6).

Comment: I would have done `dict(zip(("text_" + x for x in a), ("stuff " + x for x in a)))` but dict comprehension, as mentioned in the answers, is a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
{'text_%s' %x: 'stuff %s' %x for x in a}
```

In newer versions:

```
{f'text_{x}': f'stuff {x}' for x in a}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dictionary comprehensions:

```py
a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
my_dict = {f'key_{k}':f'val_{k}' for k in a}
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'key_aa': 'val_aa', 'key_bb': 'val_bb', 'key_cc': 'val_cc'}
```

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/
- [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)