# How to convert list into json format in python

Tags: python, json

```
x=json.dumps(result)
print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
['Client Name:'Sriram',
 'Trade Date :'03-09-2019',
 'Security :CERAMICIST-ICICLE,NAT CO - PHARMA',
 'Quantity:14,2',
 'Net Rate: 145.7500,552.3725',
 'Buy/Sell :'Buy ', 'Buy',
 'Net Total:2040.5000,1104.7450']
```

and I want to convert this list into a **json format** like this:

```
{'Client Name': Sriram',
 'Trade Date' :03-09-2019',
 'Security' :['CERAMICIST-ICICLE','NAT CO - PHARMA',
 'Quantity':'14,2',
 'Net Rate':['145.7500','552.3725'],
 'Buy/Sell':['Buy','Sell',
 'Net Total':['2040.5000','1104.7450']
```

Comment: please share your list

Comment: ['TradeDate :03-09-2019',
 'Security :ICICIPRAMCICICI500',
 'Quantity :14',
 'NetSale: 145.7500',
 'Buy/Sell :2040.5000BuyINF109KC1CZ3']

Comment: hold on... your result is not valid json.  do you mean `{'TradeDate' : '03-09-2019', ...}` or `['TradeDate :03-09-2019',....]` ?

Comment: If someone has solved your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer. If your problem is still problem, do comment what's the issue!

Comment: yes issue is there

Comment: {'Client Name': Sriram',
 'Trade Date' :03-09-2019',
 'Security' :['CERAMICIST-ICICLE','NAT CO - PHARMA',
 'Quantity':'14,2',
 'Net Rate':['145.7500','552.3725'],
 'Buy/Sell':['Buy','Sell',
 'Net Total':['2040.5000','1104.7450']

Comment: output should come like this

Answer (score 0):

One Liner in Python using [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension). We need to first convert it in `dict` using dict comprehension and then use `json.dumps()` to convert it to `json` format.

```
li = ['TradeDate :03-09-2019',
 'Security :ICICIPRAMCICICI500',
 'Quantity :14',
 'NetSale: 145.7500',
 'Buy/Sell :2040.5000BuyINF109KC1CZ3']


di = {i.split(':')[0]:i.split(':')[1] for i in li}
print(di)
js = json.dumps(di)
print(js)
```

Outputs:

```
{'TradeDate ': '03-09-2019', 'Security ': 'ICICIPRAMCICICI500', 'Quantity ': '14', 'NetSale': ' 145.7500', 'Buy/Sell ': '2040.5000BuyINF109KC1CZ3'}

{"TradeDate ": "03-09-2019", "Security ": "ICICIPRAMCICICI500", "Quantity ": "14", "NetSale": " 145.7500", "Buy/Sell ": "2040.5000BuyINF109KC1CZ3"}
```

Comment: what you are doing is dict comprehension instead of list comprehension

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in comment, your result is not a valid JSON.

Let me have these assumption:

1. You have a list of string, and for each string it is in form of `key : value`
2. You want a JSON string like

   ```
   { "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : "value2",...}
   ```

   (i.e. all key and values are string)

You could just construct a dict, with each line in the list become an entry of dict, and then use `json.dumps`.

If you need to preserve the type of the value (e.g. `123` should be a number instead of string:  `"key1" : 123`), then it is more complicated: you may need to check the format of the value and convert it to correct type

Another choice is, as `key: value` is a valid entry in YAML (note the missing double quote and the space after colon), you can do simple massaging in your message and construct a yaml string, use yaml parser to parse it to a dict, and then use json parser to construct a json string.  Something like:

```
import yaml
import json
l = [ "a:b", "c: 123", "d: true"]
result = json.dumps(
            yaml.load("\n".join( 
                      [ t[0] + ": " + t[1] for t in 
                          [ s.split(":", 1) for s in l]
                      ])))
# result string is '{"a": "b", "c": 123, "d": true}'
```