# how to remove nested dictionaries where all elements inside are None

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

For example i have this nested `dict`:

```
nest_dic = {"dict_1":{"hello":"world", "python":"programming"}, "dict_2": {"tech":"geekbuzz", "OS":None}, "dict_3": {"fruit":None, "PRICE":None}}
```

I need to get:

```
new_dest_dic = {"dict_1":{"hello":"world", "python":"programming"}, "dict_2": {"tech":"geekbuzz", "OS":None}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in here with a [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
>>> {k: v1 for k, v1 in nest_dic.items() if any(v2 is not None for v2 in v1.values())}
{'dict_1': {'hello': 'world', 'python': 'programming'}, 'dict_2': {'tech': 'geekbuzz', 'OS': None}}
```

Which keeps sub dictionaries that have *any* value that is not `None`.

You could also use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) built-in function here as well:

```
>>> {k: v1 for k, v1 in nest_dic.items() if not all(v2 is None for v2 in v1.values())}
{'dict_1': {'hello': 'world', 'python': 'programming'}, 'dict_2': {'tech': 'geekbuzz', 'OS': None}}
```

Which keeps Which keeps sub dictionaries that *all* don't have values that are `None`.

Also as a side note for `None` comparisons, from *Programming Recommendations* in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.
>
> Also, beware of writing `if x` when you really mean `if x is not None` — e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value.  The other value might have a type (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!