# Put multiple lists as value with one list as key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have 3 `lists` and one `string` like this:

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [10, 11, 14, 15, 16]

string = 'buy'
```

I need a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'a':1 , 'b':10 , 'c':'buy'},{'a':2 , 'b':11 , 'c':'buy'},{'a':3 , 'b':14 , 'c':'buy'},...]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = [ dict(zip(a,[*v, 'buy'])) for v in zip(b,c) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just zip `b` and `c` and use it to make the dictionaries in a comprehension:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [10, 11, 14, 15, 16]

[{'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':'buy'} for a, b, in zip(b,c)]
```

Result:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 11, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 14, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 15, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 5, 'b': 16, 'c': 'buy'}]
```

If you want to include the keys from `a` dynamically, you can zip them in too with something like itertools `zip_longest` to grab the static string:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [10, 11, 14, 15, 16]

[dict(zip_longest(a, tup, fillvalue='buy')) for tup in zip(b,c)]
```

Same result:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 11, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 14, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 15, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 5, 'b': 16, 'c': 'buy'}]
```

Yet another way is to use `itertools.repeat()` to include the static string in the zipped tuple:

```
from itertools import repeat

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [10, 11, 14, 15, 16]

[dict(zip(a, tup)) for tup in zip(b,c, repeat('buy'))]
```

Comment: This does sort of ignore the first list

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
[{a[0]:vb, a[1]:vc, a[2]:string} for vb, vc in zip(b, c)]
```

It produces:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 11, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 14, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 15, 'c': 'buy'},
 {'a': 5, 'b': 16, 'c': 'buy'}]
```

It takes the dict keys from list `a`, and `'buy'` comes from `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) for your task

Try this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [10, 11, 14, 15, 16]

print([{ a[0]:i, a[1]:j, a[2]:'buy'} for i,j in zip(b,c)])
```

OR

```
print([dict(zip(a, [i, j, "buy"])) for i,j in zip(b,c)])
```

Outputs:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 'buy'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 11, 'c': 'buy'}, {'a': 3, 'b': 14, 'c': 'buy'}, {'a': 4, 'b': 15, 'c': 'buy'}, {'a': 5, 'b': 16, 'c': 'buy'}]
```