# Filter dictionary by keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Input

```
dict = {
    "samp1": "x",
    "samp2": "x",
    "exp1": "x"
}

ex = dict((k, v) for k, v in dict.items() if k in samp+str(range(1,10)))
```

Expected Output

```
ex = {
    "samp1":"x",
    "samp2":"x"
}
```

My code get error in this line `str(range(1,10))`.

How can do like this  `if k in samp1 samp2 samp3...samp10` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out what's wrong in your code, I have tried to modify min. Try this (One using [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and [dict-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)):

```
dict={
    "samp1":"x",
    "samp2":"x",
    "exp1":"x"
}
li = [F"samp{i}" for i in range(1,11)]
ex = {k:v for k, v in dict.items() if k in li}
print(ex)
```

Output:

```
{'samp1': 'x', 'samp2': 'x'}
```

Another one (Thanks to @OlvinRoght for `isDecimal`.):

```
dict = {
    "samp1":"x",
    "samp2":"x",
    "samp12":"x",
    "samp":"x",
    "sampxyz":"x",
    "exp1":"x"
}
ex = {k:v for k, v in dict.items() if k.startswith("samp") and k[4:].isdecimal() and (0 < int(k[4:]) <= 10) }
print(ex)
```

Output:

```
{'samp1': 'x', 'samp2': 'x'}
```

Comment: @abhiarora's answer worked (also thanks olvin i'll try your answer)

Comment: You're creating that list *and* iterating over it *n* times... Perhaps define it outside of the list-comp?

Comment: Sure. Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `re.match` here to check if a `key` begins with the specified pattern:

```
import re
{k:v for k, v in d.items() if re.match(r'^samp[0-9]', k)}
# {'samp1': 'x', 'samp2': 'x'}
```

Alternatively you can use `startswith`, which can also take a `tuple`:

```
m = tuple(['samp'+str(i) for i in range(10)],)
{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith(m)}
# {'samp1': 'x', 'samp2': 'x'}
```

Comment: To match *samp10* you need `^samp[0-9]+`

Comment: It matches the beginning of the string anyway. I just keep the key if there is a match, i *don't* keep the match in itself @OlvinRoght

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
ex = {}
for obj in dict:
    if obj.startswith('samp'):
        ex[obj] = dict[obj]
print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `filter` and regexp:

```
import re

idict = { 
    "samp1": "x",
    "samp2": "x",
    "exp1": "x" 
}

MATCH = re.compile(r'samp[1-9]')
odict = dict(filter(lambda kv: MATCH.fullmatch(kv[0]), idict.items()))
print(odict)
```

---

Update: If the number of keys is always low like in the question, it might be more efficent to retrieve just those few keys (if present, of course). Something like:

```
mykeys = ["samp1", ..., "samp9"]
odict = {key: idict[key] for key in mykeys if key in idict}
```