# Comparing the values of 2 Dictionaries with non matched values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to compare the values of 2 Dictionaries and create a new dictionary containing keys of 1st dictionary with non matched values

```
D1 = {'ID1': ['Name'], 'ID2': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product'], 'ID3': ['Name', 'team']}
D2 = {'SNO': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product']}
```

I can take D2 as list also:
`D2 = ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product']`

Expected result should be:

```
{'ID1': [ 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product'], 'ID2': [], 'ID3': [ 'email', 'environment', 'product']}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some easy dict-comprehension if there is no specific requirements:

```
D1 = {'ID1': ['Name'], 'ID2': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product'], 'ID3': ['Name', 'team']}
D2 = {'SNO': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product']}

print({i: list(set(D2['SNO'])-set(D1[i])) for i in D1})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. its working :) but may i know where you are appending into new dictionary? you are just printing

Comment: @SirishaM Learn something about [dict-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) and [list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is check if one of D2 is not in one of D1's arrays. This can be achieved with the following for loops:

```
D1 = {'ID1': ['Name'], 'ID2': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product'], 'ID3': ['Name', 'team']}
D2 = {'SNO': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product']}

diff = {'ID1': [], 'ID2': [], 'ID3': []} 
for i in D1:
    for j in D2['SNO']:
        if j not in D1[i]:
            diff[i].append(j)
print(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the values of each key from dict 1 **D1** with values in value from dict **D2**. You could do it in 3 lines.

```
D1 = {'ID1': ['Name'], 'ID2': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product'], 'ID3': ['Name', 'team']}
D2 = {'SNO': ['Name', 'email', 'environment', 'team', 'product']}

missing_values = {}
for k, v in D1.items():
    missing_values[k] = list(set(D2["SNO"]) - set(v))

print(missing_values)
```

Comment: Thank you. This one working well. result in new dictionary