# How to create a dictionary from a string in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```py
my_str = 'wednesday'
```

**Output should be**

```
d = {'w':1,'e':2,'d':2,'n':1,'s':1,'y':1,'a':1}
```

Is there any direct inbuilt function?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import collections
>>> s = 'wednesday'
>>> collections.Counter(s)
Counter({'e': 2, 'd': 2, 'w': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1, 'a': 1, 'y': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "wednesday"
dic = dict()
for character in string:
  dic[character] = dic.get(character, 0) + 1
print (dic)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the dictionary comprehension, as explained in this answer : [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

```
my_str = 'wednesday'
d = { ch:(my_str.count(ch)) for ch in my_str }
print(d)
```

Comment: @OP This is called dictionary comprehension.

Comment: This is unecessarily quadratic time

Comment: This is O(N**2) when it can be done in O(N) trivially. Don't use `.count` in a loop