# Create as many columns as necessary & use them to place output of .apply() in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
# import modules, set seed
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
random.seed(42)
```

---

## The problem

I am having a dataframe `df`. Its rows contain values which are input to a function, producing *variable* number of outputs. The maximum number of outputs is not known a priori. The **outputs are to be put in the same row as the function, creating new columns if necessary**. Unfilled cells should be filled with `NaN`s.

---

## Reproducible setup

Let's create a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(5)]),columns=['randomnums'])
```

This looks like:

[image]

---

## What have I done

Created a dataframe (`auxiliarydf`) with the values I want to fill the rows of the to-be created columns of the original `df`, using [from_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful/890188), [dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) & [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520):

```
auxiliarydf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
                {index: pd.Series(array) for index, array in zip(
                         df.index,
                         df['randomnums'].apply(
                                          lambda r: 
                                          # here I apply some function on the row.
                                          # The output will be a list of variable length
                                          # for the shake of an example:
                                          np.array([x for x in range(r)])))},
                orient='index')
```

`auxiliarydf` will be:

[image]

[concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) `df` with `auxiliarydf`:

```
pd.concat([df, auxiliarydf], axis=1)
```

Result:

[image]

Which is as expected.

---

## The question

Is there an easier, maybe built-in Pandas function to do the process above? It works, but it seems like a problem which appears with enough frequency to expect a neater solution.

---

*Colab notebook available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16xp-sw3GYItg7uXQgWFyQzEojDRbIjit?usp=sharing) with the code above.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try with directly creating a dataframe using the `pd.DataFrame` constructor and using the existing dataframe index and calling a [`series.tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) to the resultant series of arrays, then you can use [`df.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
auxillary_df = df['randomnums'].apply(lambda r: np.array([x for x in range(r)]))
df.join(pd.DataFrame(auxillary_df.to_list(),index=df.index))
```

---

```
   randomnums  0    1    2    3    4
0           2  0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1           1  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2           5  0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
3           4  0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
4           4  0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
```

Of course you can chain them to get a one liner , however readability first :)

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['randomnums'].apply(lambda r:
    np.array([x for x in range(r)])).to_list(),index=df.index))
```