# Using list instead of dictionary for organized results

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, sum

I'm trying to get my code below working to have the results organized rather than random.

This is what's happening now.

```
sum = 9 count = 117
sum = 6 count = 142
sum = 3 count = 58
sum = 7 count = 172
sum = 8 count = 129
sum = 5 count = 109
sum = 4 count = 87
sum = 11 count = 53
sum = 12 count = 31
sum = 10 count = 72
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is

```
    sum = 1 count = 117
    sum = 2 count = 142
    sum = 3 count = 58
    sum = 4 count = 172
    sum = 5 count = 129
    sum = 6 count = 109
    sum = 7 count = 87
    sum = 8 count = 53
    sum = 12 count = 31
```

etc. While omitting any number that hasn't been rolled.
I'd ideally like to use a list instead of a dictionary but any time I try it I get varying errors.
Currently this outputs the amount but not in order.

```
    import random
    
    print("results")
    occurrences = []
    for i in range(1000):
        die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        roll = die1 + die2
        current = occurrences[roll, ]
        occurrences[roll] = current + 1
    
    for roll, count in occurrences[]
        print(f"sum = {roll} count = {count}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recipe for dictionary-based roll occurrence counting would be:

1. First initialize all roll possibilities within a dictionary (the example below makes use of [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)) where the dict *keys* are the roll value and the dict *values* are the corresponding occurence.
2. Count each time a roll happens with the `+=1` statement (in-place add up 1).
3. Sort the dictionary with another dictionary comprehension operated on the sorted dictionary values (here, the occurrence of each roll).
4. Loop over the dictionary *keys* (rolls) and corresponding *values* (occurrences) in order to show the output.

**Here is your code with the above statements included**:

```
import random

print("results")
occurrences = {k: 0 for k in range(2, 13)}

for i in range(10000):
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = die1 + die2
    occurrences[roll] += 1

occurrences = {k: v for k, v in sorted(occurrences.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

for roll, count in occurrences.items():
    print(f"sum = {roll} count = {count}")
```

which outputs the following result with 10,000 rolls:

```
sum = 7 count = 1653
sum = 6 count = 1398
sum = 8 count = 1325
sum = 5 count = 1162
sum = 9 count = 1142
sum = 10 count = 842
sum = 4 count = 812
sum = 11 count = 578
sum = 3 count = 540
sum = 2 count = 295
sum = 12 count = 253
```