# How Does Extracting Of a Value From Dictionary Work?

Tags: python

```
sampleDict = {
  "name": "Kelly",
  "age":25,
  "salary": 8000,
  "city": "New york"
}

keys = ["name", "salary"]
newDict = { k: sampleDict[k] for k in keys}

print(newDict)
```

Comment: What are you trying to extract here?? Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: Are you asking how sampleDict[k] returns the appropriate value?

Comment: What is your question? The new dictionary is generated using [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension), where the keys you've given it "transfers" the key/value pairs to a new dictionary.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension) helps?

Comment: To `extract` values from a Python dictionary, you have to provide the key, e.g., `print(newDict["name"])` should print `"Kelly"`

Answer (score 1):

It might be clearer what's happening if you avoid using dictionary comprehension (where the loop happens inside `{}`.

The new dictionary is generated by `{ k: sampleDict[k] for k in keys}`, but we can rewrite that to be more explicit:

```
sample_dict = {"name": "Kelly", "age":25, "salary": 8000, "city": "New york"}
keys_to_keep = ["name", "salary"]
new_dict = {}

for key in keys_to_keep:
    new_dict[key] = sample_dict[key]

print(new_dict)
```

In effect, for each key referenced in `keys_to_keep`, copy the existing value from `sample_dict` and store it under the same key in `new_dict`.