# Python expand a dict() to add a static element

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

How do I create `p` below?

Is this a list comprehension & .map() problem?

`pr = [{"pr":"DEV"}, {"pr":"STEVE"}]`

`spr = "what"`

`p = [{"pr":"DEV", "spr":"what"}, {"pr":"STEVE", "spr":"what"}]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: First of all, why do you want to create such a wastefull and complex data structure? I suggest implementing a class which has the "spr" and the list of "pr". Also, LPT: use better variable names, you will sometimes read code you wrote a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merge the dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/967621) inside the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
pr = [{"pr":"DEV"}, {"pr":"STEVE"}]
spr = "what"
p = [{**x, **{'spr': spr}} for x in pr]
print(p)
# [{'pr': 'DEV', 'spr': 'what'}, {'pr': 'STEVE', 'spr': 'what'}]
```

Comment: I couldn't recognize this a dict merge problem.  But is certainly is one if you create dict out of `spr` on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Given an arbitrary list of `pr` values, you can use

```
p = [{"pr": k, "spr": spr} for k in pr]
```

To handle the edit,

```
p = [dict(**x, spr=spr) for x in pr]
# In Python 3.9, 
# p = [x | {"spr": spr} for x in pr]
```

Comment: I'm sorry man.  Maybe I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  You cannot believe my how far flung my work got before I posted this.

Comment: To make this more interesting I edited my OP.  Notice the difference in `pr`; list of a object.