# Convert first 2 elements of a dictionary array to tuple

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, tuples

How can I convert the first 2 elements of each array into tuple index?

Current

```
 {0: [1, 1, 0],
 1: [1, 2, 357],
 2: [1, 3, 167],
 3: [1, 4, 155]}
```

Desired Outcome

```
 {(1, 1): 0,
  (1, 2): 357,
  (1, 3): 167,
  (1, 4): 155}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Did your code fail?

Comment: What should happen if they produce the same tuple?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) in the following way:

```
d = {0: [1, 1, 0],1: [1, 2, 357],2: [1, 3, 167],3: [1, 4, 155]}
res = {(v[0],v[1]):v[2] for v in d.values()}
```

Where `res` is:

```
{(1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 357, (1, 3): 167, (1, 4): 155}
```

This solution will be problematic if you have duplicate tuples. You should address it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the dictionary's values and use tuple unpacking to extract three elements. Pack the first two elements inside a tuple as a key. Assign the last element as a value of the new tuple.

```
dictionary = {
    0:[1,1,0],
    1:[1,2,357],
    2:[1,3,167],
    3:[1,4,155],
}
result = {(j,k):i for j,k,i in dictionary.values()}
```

or

```
result = {}
for j,k,i in dictionary.values():
    result[(j,k)] = i
```