# Python dictionary keys changed during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, python-3.5

I have a dict like this:

```
     d={
         'McAfee': {'DatDate': '123','DatVersion': '456'},
         'AntiVirus': {'AVName': ['Mac Defender', 'Windows Defender'],'AVVersion': ['262144', '393472']}
       }
```

Now I want to change the key of d and change the value's key of d too according to this mapping:

```
mapping_table = {"McAfee":'Mc_table','AntiVirus':'An_table'}

mapping_coulmn = {'DatDate':"Dc_column",'AVName':'Av_column','DatVersion':'Da_column','AVVersion':'AVV_column'}
```

The output should like:

```
 d={
    'Mc_table': {'Dc_column': '123','Da_column': '456'},
    'An_table': {'Av_column': ['Mac Defender', 'Windows Defender'],'AVV_column': ['262144', '393472']}
    }
```

What I tired is:

```
for key in d:
    if key in mapping_table:
        new_key = mapping_table[key]
        d1[new_key]=d.pop(key)
        
print(d)
```

It returns an error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

Any friend can help?Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have to modify the dictionary in place instead of returning a new dictionary?

Comment: I have no idea who edited this question and says it is duplicate, it is similar but not duplicate at all,I ask the person who edited my question to remove the duplicate tag!

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate? `d.pop(key)` deletes from the dictionary. The other question explains how to delete from a dictionary while looping over it.

Comment: In that question,the person wanted to del the key ,but I want to replace key and my dict structure is nested his is not.

Comment: There's no way to replace keys directly. All you can do is delete the old key and add a new key, which is what you're doing. But you can't modify keys while iterating. The other question provides the solution.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {
    mapping_table.get(k, k): {
        mapping_column.get(kk, kk): vv for kk, vv in v.items()
    }
    for k, v in d.items()
}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'Mc_table': {'Dc_column': '123', 'Da_column': '456'}, 
 'An_table': {'Av_column': ['Mac Defender', 'Windows Defender'], 
              'AVV_column': ['262144', '393472']}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer,bu can you add some explain about this line:vv for kk, vv in v.items()

Comment: @William `mapping_column.get(kk, kk): vv for kk, vv in v.items()` This line will iterate over every key, value in the dictionary, then tries to apply the mapping on key with `mapping_column.get(kk, kk)` (I use .`get()`, because if the value is not found in the mapping, the original key is returned - instead of an error)

Comment: How can you iterate or loop such big logic only use 1 line? Please teach me!!For me,the first thing in my mind I will use something like for key in mapping_column:....but you just use 1 line!!!

Comment: @William Python has concept of dictionary comprehension (for lists, sets too). It's really useful to learn them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension

Comment: Can you let me know,what is this line mean:vv for kk, vv in v.items(),is it same as for vv in kk or something else?!