# Deleting duplicates from a dictionary's value pairs in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

In python I have some code that extracts data from text files, then stores each word and what file they appear in, in a dictionary. It looks something like this:

```
{'apple': [1, 1, 4, 5], 'carrot': [1, 2, 2], 'pear': [1, 3, 3, 6]}
```

but a lot bigger with a lot more files.

I want some code that will delete the duplicates in the value pairs. Right now it's telling me every time a word appears in a file, but I just want to know if it appears in  each file. So I want my dictionary to look like this:

```
{'apple': [1, 4, 5], 'carrot': [1, 2], 'pear': [1, 3, 6]}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `set(…)` is your friend here.

Comment: `{k:list(dict.fromkeys(v)) for k,v in data.items()}` if you want to maintain order

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using [dict comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
adict = {'apple': [1, 1, 4, 5], 'carrot': [1, 2, 2], 'pear': [1, 3, 3, 6]}

print({k: list(dict.fromkeys(v)) for k, v in adict.items()})
```